# Is False == 0 and True == 1 an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?

Tags: python, boolean, equality, language-specifications

Is it guaranteed that `False == 0` and `True == 1`, in Python (assuming that they are not reassigned by the user)?  For instance, is it in any way guaranteed that the following code will always produce the same results, whatever the version of Python (both existing and, likely, future ones)?

```
0 == False  # True
1 == True   # True
['zero', 'one'][False]  # is 'zero'
```

Any reference to the official documentation would be much appreciated!

As noted in many answers, `bool` inherits from `int`.  The question can therefore be recast as: "Does the documentation officially say that programmers can rely on booleans inheriting from integers, *with the values `0` and `1`*?".  This question is relevant for writing robust code that won't fail because of implementation details!

Comment: @S.Lott: There are many reasons to ask the question above.  Thus, there are instances where relying on booleans being integer makes your code simpler: do you have to change it?  Or, you might spot places in a code written by someone else that relies on booleans being integers: do you interrupt what you are modifying in the code in order to "fix" existing code, or can you rest assured that the current coding is sound?  There is a plethora of other examples.  More generally, it is good to know the rules of the game, so that you can play it well and program in a sound way.

Comment: @EOL: can you provide an example of "relying on booleans being integer makes your code simpler"?  I can't imagine such a thing.  " do you interrupt what you are modifying in the code in order to "fix" existing code, or can you rest assured that the current coding is sound?" The question seems technical, not "how do I cope?"  The rules are simple:  **don't depend on implementation details**.  So why ask about an implementation detail?

Comment: @S.Lott: The original post precisely echoes your point: the question is essentially "Is this an implementation detail?", because I fully agree with you on the idea that one should not depend on implementation details.  If booleans are officially integers of known values, then the code in the question does not rely on implementation details, which is good.

Comment: @S. Lot: Knowing that False==0 and True==1 makes it easier to count how many bools in a sequence are true:  You can just write `sum(bool_list)`.  Otherwise, you'd have to write `sum(1 for x bool_list if x)`.

Comment: @dan: That's one way of counting booleans.  I would say that `bool_list.count(True)` is more explicit; it's also about 3 times faster… :)

Comment: Treating booleans as integers is a type error. If Python had types. I would not make errors in code.

Comment: @akonsu As the answers show, Python booleans *are* actually (a specific subclass of) integers. Furthermore, Python obviously *has* types; maybe you meant that it is "not statically typed"? Also, I am not sure what you mean by "I would not make errors in code". Now, I never like mixing booleans with integers, because they are conceptually different, and I would not mind if Python booleans were not integers, but knowing that they are, with values 0 and 1, is useful.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

In Python 2.x this is *not* guaranteed as it is possible for `True` and `False` to be reassigned.  However, even if this happens, boolean True and boolean False are still properly returned for comparisons.

In Python 3.x `True` and `False` are keywords and will always be equal to `1` and `0`.

Under normal circumstances in Python 2, and always in Python 3:

`False` object is of type `bool` which is a subclass of `int`:

```text
    object
       |
     int
       |
     bool
```

It is the only reason why in your example, `['zero', 'one'][False]` does work. It would not work with an object which is not a subclass of integer, because list indexing only works with integers, or objects that define a [`__index__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) method (thanks [mark-dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson)).

Edit:

It is true of the current python version, and of that of Python 3. The [docs for python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-10) and the [docs for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10) both say:

> There are two types of integers: [...] Integers (int) [...] Booleans (bool)

and in the boolean subsection:

> Booleans: These represent the truth values False and True [...] Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

There is also, [for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values):

> In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they [False and True] behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively.

So booleans are explicitly considered as integers in Python 2 and 3.

So you're safe until Python 4 comes along. ;-)

Comment: 0 == 0.0 returns True while ['zero', 'one'][0.0] fails. ['zero', 'one'][False] works because bool is a subclass of int. (int.__subclasses__() returns [<type 'bool'>])

Comment: Nitpick:  any object that provides an `__index__` method can be used as a list index; not just subclasses of `int` or `long`.

Comment: Ah yes, it's there too.  But it would be better not to link to the Python 3.0 documentation:  3.0 is dead. :)

Comment: Re: "In Python 2.x this is not guaranteed as it is possible for True and False to be reassigned". IMHO, while this is true, anyone who reassigns True or False deserves whatever strange consequences they get. Specifically, storing True before the reassignment and then comparing the result to True after reassignment would break. `a = True; True = 'i am an idiot'; a == True` => False. Other than such reassignment, the default values are standardized as 0 and 1, and I believe it is common practice to depend on that; e.g. to index into a two-element array, where [0] holds the false case, [1] true.

Comment: I just noticed another official confirmation of the fact that True can in practice be considered like 1 and False 0: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values. I'm adding this to this answer.

Comment: Upvoting for the small shred of hope that Python 4 will fix this.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 87):

Here's the PEP discussing the new bool type in Python 2.3: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/.

When converting a bool to an int, the integer value is always 0 or 1, but when converting an int to a bool, the boolean value is True for all integers except 0.

```
>>> int(False)
0
>>> int(True)
1
>>> bool(5)
True
>>> bool(-5)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

Comment: Since you give examples of bool conversion, I want to point something out I just ran across that caused a bug in my code bool('0') is True

Answer (score 23):

In Python 2.x, it is not guaranteed at all:

```
>>> False = 5
>>> 0 == False
False
```

So it could change. In Python 3.x, True, False, and None are [reserved words](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax), so the above code would not work.

In general, with booleans you should assume that while False will always have an integer value of 0 (so long as you don't change it, as above), True could have any other value. I wouldn't necessarily rely on any guarantee that `True==1`, but on Python 3.x, this will always be the case, no matter what.

Comment: Re " True could have any other value. I wouldn't necessarily rely on any guarantee that True==1".  Actually, you CAN rely on True==1, as per http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/ , and spec http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy  "Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts..."  I'm not saying it is impossible to override this in Py 2 by reassigning True or False, but I am saying that unless some programmer on your project is an idiot and does such a reassignment, the behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: BTW sometimes get problem to switch too python style. Examle:
```
if not (2 != 2): # <== thats ok
 print ("Hello, world!")
if ! (1 != 2): # <== SyntaxError
 print ("Hello, world!")
``` https://rextester.com/VSTV98648

Comment: When it says that `0==False` is `False`, does that actually mean that it's `5` ?

Comment: This confuses the *name* `False` with the value of type `bool` bound to the name in the builtin scope. The Boolean value is always equal to 0, no matter what value might be assigned to the name.

Answer (score 2):

*Let's break this question into two parts.*

## Python:

```
print(45 == "45")  # Output - False
```

---

## Javascript:

```
console.log(45 == "45")  # Output - true
```

Here, most people think Javascript only checks the value of both side object, But that's not true writing `console.log(45 == "45")` is similar to `print(45 == "45")`. 
But now you have a question if both syntax are similar why do I get different results?

In `Javascript` :

- The `==` operator performs type coercion before comparing the values. This means that JavaScript will attempt to convert the operands to a common type before evaluating the equality.
- In the case of `45 == "45"` in JavaScript, the string `"45"` is automatically converted to a number because the other operand is a number. JavaScript tries to perform implicit type conversion to make the comparison. The string `"45"` can be converted to the number `45`, and hence the comparison `45 == "45"` evaluates to `true`.
- Similar to Python keyword `is`, Javascript has a `===` Comparison Operator. Which checks both of side object is located in the same computer RAM memory location or not.

In `Python` :

- In the Python, `45` and `"45"` have different types. `45` is an instance of `class <integer>`, and `"45"` is an instance of `class <string>`. They are not instances of the same class.
- Unlike Javascript, Python doesn't do internal type conversion, So `print(45 == "45")` evaluates `False`.
- Python used internal type conversion, Yes you heard right but here is one condition. Python will use internal type conversion only with `boolean` type objects.
- So, in the expression `print(True == 1)`, the boolean value True is implicitly coerced to the integer `1` before performing the comparison. As a result, the comparison `print(1 == 1)` is evaluated, which is `True`.
- When you write `print(True == 1)` is equivalent to `print(1 == 1)`. When Python interpreter reaches this code of line before executing this code it is convert `print(True == 1)` to `print(int(True) == 1)`, So finally it becomes `print(1 == 1)` and now according to `==` rule both side object `value` and `type <class int>` are same hence you see `True` output in terminal.
- Similarly, `print(False == 0)` is equivalent to `print(int(False) == 0)` and finally `print(0 == 0)` evaluate to `True`.

##### Check HERE.

```
# Normal behavior
sample_1 = True
print(sample_1) # Output - True
print(int(sample_1)) # Output - 1

sample_2 = False
print(sample_2) # Output - False
print(int(sample_2)) # Output - 0


# Try with True - boolean
A = True + 5  # equivalent to `A = int(True) + 5`
print(A) # Output - 6 (True ---> 1)


# Try with False - boolean
B = False + 5 # equivalent to `A = int(False) + 5`
print(B) # Output - 5 (False ---> 0)


# Try both boolean together
final = False + True # equivalent to `final = int(False) + int(True)`
print(final) # Output - 1  (False ---> 0 & True ---> 1)
```

Hope it helps everyone!