# if else for None in Python

Tags: python

Any way to write this in one line in Python, or even better, as an expression instead of a statement?

```
parts = ['0', '1', 'None', '5', '4']
[int(p) for p in parts]
```

This of course gives an error,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

So:

```
[p=='None' and None or int(p) for p in parts]
```

Doesn't work because you can't use `None` with the and/or construct reliably.  (Even if `p=='None'` is true, `None` is equivalent to false so it goes to the `or` part.)

```
[int(p) if p=='None' else None for p in parts]
```

Also doesn't work.  I guess it evaluates `int(p)` before the conditions?  (Seems odd semantics.)

```
a = []
for p in parts:
    if p=='None': k = None; else: k = int(p)
    a.append(k)
```

Nope, invalid syntax.

```
a = []
for p in parts:
    if p=='None':
        k = None;
    else:
        k = int(p)
    a.append(k)
```

Ah! Finally.  But isn't there a shorter way to write such a simple loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You almost got it right:

```
[None if p == 'None' else int(p) for p in parts]
```

Comment: +1 This is the Python form of the [conditional ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29#As_a_ternary_operator): `when-true if expr else when-false` which maps to the C form of `expr ? when-true : when-false` (the operator is lazy in both languages)

Comment: Or the more powerful (and dangerous) `map(eval, parts)`

Comment: @6502: Or the less dangerous `map(ast.literal_eval, parts)`.

Comment: Reference: [5.11 Conditional Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Is there a place to submit a "comment of the day" award?  that's brilliant?

Comment: A second thought: this seems to count on the fact that None is trivial to evaluate, but I still think it's weird that the part before 'if' gets evaluated first.  If I wasn't using None, but calling a function or something, then it would be evaluated regardless of the condition, no?

Comment: @Steve: The condition gets evaluated first, and after it only the part the needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 7):

Almost had it:

```
[int(p) if p != 'None' else None for p in parts]
```

Comment: A more legible improvement on Sven Marnach's accepted version. Better to put the common case first.

Answer (score 4):

```
[ [int, eval] [p=='None'] (p) for p in parts]
```

Should be save as eval is only called on string 'None'.

Comment: I had no idea you could index arrays with booleans.  I'd say the syntax is pretty unpythonic, but it's still pretty cool.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. I'll probably stick to if-else for clarity but it's a good answer too.

Comment: @intractelicious: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints/3175293#3175293 for a discussion if this is "Pythonic".

Comment: Actually I personally use these constructs excessively. Let sendSMTP, sendVoice and SensGSM be functions. So I call {'mail': sendSMTP, 'sip': sendVoice, 'sms': SendGSM} [protocol] (message). To send a message depending on its protocol (being in this case one of the dictionary keys.)

Comment: Same, I've always used this construct as a switch-statement replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really only have 1 place in your code where you need this transform?  If not, define a function and then make it multiple lines, commented, and easy to follow.  That way you hide the complexity of your code, and keep the main code simple to read.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution will be:

```
parts = ['0', '1', 'None', '5', '4']
[int(p) for p in parts if p.isdigit()]
```

However, float is not accepted here. If float string(?? I dont know what to call that) to integer is a necessity, you can consider the following:

```
parts = ['0', '1', 'None', '5', '4']
[int(p.split(".")[0]) for p in parts if p.replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()]
```