# Why is bool a subclass of int?

Tags: python, boolean

When storing a bool in memcached through python-memcached I noticed that it's returned as an integer. Checking the code of the library showed me that there is a place where `isinstance(val, int)` is checked to flag the value as an integer.

So I tested it in the python shell and noticed the following:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

But why exactly is `bool` a subclass of `int`?

It kind of makes sense because a boolean basically is an int which can just take two values but it needs much less operations/space than an actual integer (no arithmetics, only a single bit of storage space)....

Comment: Here's [Alex Martelli's take on a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints/3175293#3175293).

Comment: It's worth noting that since in Python, everything is an object, with the overhead that employs, it's pretty much pointless to try to save space by making `bool`s smaller. If you cared about memory use, you'd be using a different language to begin with.

Comment: Also there's only one copy of `True` and `False` in the entire process, so saving a few bytes on those two specific objects would have basically no impact on anything.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

From a comment on http://www.peterbe.com/plog/bool-is-int

> It is perfectly logical, if you were around when the bool type was
>   added to python (sometime around 2.2 or 2.3).
>
> Prior to introduction of an actual bool type, 0 and 1 were the
>   official representation for truth value, similar to C89. To avoid
>   unnecessarily breaking non-ideal but working code, the new bool type
>   needed to work just like 0 and 1. This goes beyond merely truth value,
>   but all integral operations. No one would recommend using a boolean
>   result in a numeric context, nor would most people recommend testing
>   equality to determine truth value, no one wanted to find out the hard
>   way just how much existing code is that way. Thus the decision to make
>   True and False masquerade as 1 and 0, respectively. This is merely a
>   historical artifact of the linguistic evolution.

Credit goes to dman13 for this nice explanation.

Comment: Note that this might be historically true, but idiomatically you see a lot of `sum([f(value) for value in values])` where `f(x)` is some sort of filter function and you need to see how many values pass the filter.

Comment: Personally I would rather write `sum(1 for value in values if f(value))`, but I've actually seen respected people advocate in favor of numerical operations on bools.

Answer (score 33):

See [PEP 285 -- Adding a bool type](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).  Relevent passage:

> 6) Should bool inherit from int?
>
> => Yes.
>
> In an ideal world, bool might be better implemented as a
>      separate integer type that knows how to perform mixed-mode
>      arithmetic.  However, inheriting bool from int eases the
>      implementation enormously (in part since all C code that calls
>      PyInt_Check() will continue to work -- this returns true for
>      subclasses of int).

Answer (score 0):

Can also use `help` to check the `Bool`'s value in Console:

**help(True)**

```
help(True)
Help on bool object:
class bool(int)
 |  bool(x) -> bool
 |  
 |  Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
 |  The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
 |  The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      bool
 |      int
 |      object
 |
```

**help(False)**

```
help(False)
Help on bool object:
class bool(int)
 |  bool(x) -> bool
 |  
 |  Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
 |  The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
 |  The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      bool
 |      int
 |      object
```

Comment: You might want to comment out the help text so that it isn't syntax highlighted.