# Multiplying boolean with float?

Tags: python, type-conversion, boolean

I don't understand the line `q.append(p[i] * (hit * pHit + (1-hit) * pMiss))`, because the variable `hit` is a boolean value. That boolean value comes from `hit = (Z == world[i])`

What's going on there? I only have a basic understanding of Python...

```
p = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]

world = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green']
Z = 'red'
pHit = 0.6
pMiss = 0.2

def sense(p, Z):
    q=[]
    for i in range(len(p)):
        hit = (Z == world[i])
        q.append(p[i] * (hit * pHit + (1-hit) * pMiss))
        s = sum(q)
        for i in range(len(p)):
            q[i]=q[i]/s      
    return q

print sense(p,Z)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True is `1` and False is `0`, as others have answered. So basically, what it does (and what should've been written) is:

```
p[i] * (pHit if hit else pMiss)
```

Answer (score 17):

In arithmetic, booleans are treated as integers. `True` is treated as `1` and `False` is treated as `0`.

```
>>> True + 1
    2
>>> False * 20
    0
>>> True * 20
    20
```

Answer (score 14):

In python, booleans are a subclass of int:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```

They are basically 1 and 0:

```
>>> True * 1
1
>>> False * 1
0
```

See [Why is bool a subclass of int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int)