# Create a new column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df, need to create a new column, which is a product of `price` with `metric`(int calculated before).

```
df['cost'] = df['price'] * metric if (df['status'] == 'online')
df['cost'] = 0 if df['status'] == 'offline'
```

Answer (score 5):

We can leverage the point that `True` is 1 and `False` is 0 when used in multiplication.

```
3 * True  -> 3
3 * False -> 0
```

We have to check if values are equal to `online` in the `status` column.

```
df['cost'] = df['price'] * df['status'].eq('online') * metric
```

Wherever, `status` is `offline` `cost` value is 0.

---

The above solution relies on the fact you want to set `offline` values to 0. If you want to set `offline` to let's `999`. Then we can use `Series.where` here.

```
df['cost'] = df['price'].mul(metric).where(df['status'].eq('online'), 999)
```

Now, every `offline` value to set to `999`.

Useful links:

- [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)
- [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)
- [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html)
- [Multiplying boolean with float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13332162/12416453)

Comment: I have seen this thing first time. Feeling amazed.

Comment: @ManlaiA Thank you. `np.where` is also extensively used in these cases. Since you already answered I had to come up with something different. :p

Comment: @AnujSharma Thank you. Booleans are considered as ints when used in arithmetics. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13332162/12416453).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['cost'] = np.where(df['status']=='online', df['price']*metric, 0)
```

Comment: this is the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want plain `pandas` you can use `loc`:

```
df['cost'] = 0
df.loc[df['status']== "online" , 'cost'] = df['price'] * metric
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
df['cost'] = [df['price']*metric if status == 'online' else 0 for status in df['status']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, all of the answers here solve your problem but using np.where or np.select (already showed in above answers) is best to use because it can solve multiple conditions.

However, above solutions with np.where and np.select can give wrong output if data contains nan values.

Let me simplify and explain these two (np.select and pd.cut) for future cases also.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'status':['online','offline','away','busy',np.nan]})
df['price'] = 100
df

status  price
0   online  100
1   offline     100
2   away    100
3   busy    100
4   NaN     100
```

Let's say you have 4 conditions:

```
status = online then  df['cost'] =df['price']*metric
status = offline then df['cost'] = 0
status = away then df['cost'] = 1
status = busy then df['cost'] = 2
```

then you can just put all these conditions simply in one segment like this:

```
col         = 'status'
conditions  = [ df[col] == 'online' , (df[col] == 'offline') , (df[col]== 'away'), df[col] == 'busy']
options     = [df['price']*metric, 0, 1, 2 ]

df['cost'] = np.select(conditions, options)
```

after running this.

```
    status  price   cost
0   online  100     500
1   offline     100     0
2   away    100     1
3   busy    100     2
4   NaN     100     0
```

you can observe the value is 0 in front of nan. To tackle this problem, use:

```
df['cost'] = np.select(conditions, options,default = np.nan)
```