# Why does ~True = -2 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely perplexed. We came across a bug, which we easily fixed, but we are perplexed as to why the value the bug was generating created the output it did. Specifically:

Why does `~True` equal `-2` in python?

```
~True 
>> -2
```

Shouldn't the bitwise operator `~` only return binary?

(Python v3.8)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some code that we can copy/paste and run. Also, what do you mean by "return binary"?

Comment: Since `int(True) == 1` I presume that True is being cast to `1` before being inverted.

Comment: Complement 2 on integer representation of True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shifting and binary bitwise operators applies on boolean arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379847/shifting-and-binary-bitwise-operators-applies-on-boolean-arguments)

Comment: `True` doesn't even need to be converted: `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python. Just has a peculiar `__repr__()`.

Comment: What would you expect “binary” to look like?

Comment: Do you understand why `~1 == -2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`True` is a specialization of `int`. In python, integers are signed and unbounded. If one were to invert a fixed-size integer like the 16 bit `0x0001`, you'd get `0xfffe` which is `-2` signed. But python needs a different definition of that operation because it is not size bounded. In [Unary arithmetic and bitwise operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) python defines unary inversion as

> The unary ~ (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its
> integer argument. The bitwise inversion of x is defined as -(x+1). It
> only applies to integral numbers or to custom objects that override
> the **invert**() special method.

This has the same effect as fixed-size bit inversion without messing around with infinity. Sure enough

```
>>> -(True+1)
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the bitwise operator `~` only return binary?

Well, technically EVERYTHING in a computer is binary. However, this is only part of the story. There are two important concepts here:

1. Data types of values
2. Representations of those values

For the first one `True` is a boolean and `-2` is an integer. In some cases, Python will convert a value from one type to another in order to perform certain operations. In this case, the `~` is the bitwise operator which only works on integers. In this case, an actual conversion isn't necessary since `boolean` inherits from `int`, so the boolean value can just be treated as the integer value of `1`. Then `~` gives the bitwise inverse of that integer value.

Now if we represent the `1` in binary as `00000001` (yes, technically there are more 0s, but I'm not going to type them out...the concept still holds if we only use 8 bits instead of the actual 32 or 64), we negate this to `11111110` (again, there are more leading 1s because there are really more bits). Note that the way I write the integer value here in binary is merely a **representation** of the value using characters I can type on a keyboard. This is still `00000001` in binary and `1` in decimal both represent the same underlying value in memory. Similarly `11111110` binary and `-2` decimal both represent the same value.

At the end, `print()` will just print the value in decimal which is why you get `-2`. If you want to print the value in hex or binary, there are built in methods to get these representations instead.

Comment: There is no conversion. `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and inherits its operators.

Comment: It wasn't a detail, but a correction. But sure, you're welcome.