# Calling pd.Series.sum() breaks when using `~` operator

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum the inverse of a bool pd.Series. `pd.Series.sum()` works fine until i use the `~` operator. At which point `.sum()` starts throwing negative values.

Here is a very simple example:

`.sum()` works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series([True]).sum()
1
>>> pd.Series([False]).sum()
0
```

But when I invoke the `~` operator, things break:

```
>>> ~pd.Series([False]).sum()
-1
>>> ~pd.Series([True]).sum()
-2
```

Notably nothing seems wrong with the data:

```
>>> ~pd.Series([True])
0    False
dtype: bool
>>> ~pd.Series([False])
0    True
dtype: bool
```

What is going on here? How can I use sum on the inverse of a pd.Series object?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618364/why-does-true-2-in-python

Comment: run `print(~1)` this is property of Python bitwise operators.

Comment: the former is equivalent to `~(pd.Series([False]).sum())` and not `(~pd.Series([False])).sum()`

Comment: In general, `~` is not a Boolean operator, but Pandas overloads it as such because `not` is not customizable. Due to the precedence of attribute access over any operator, you are applying `~` to the sum as a bitwise operator, not to the `Series` as a element-wise Boolean operator.

Comment: OK, thanks. I see this is covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply `~` to the `Series`, not the result of the `Series`'s `sum` method. To do that, you need parentheses, because attribute access has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than any operator.

```
>>> pd.Series([True]).sum()
1
>>> (~pd.Series([True])).sum()
0
```