# Bool as int? How does python evaluate

Tags: python

```
In [1]: a=5

In [2]: print(["is odd", "is even"][a % 2 == 0])
is odd

In [3]: [a%2 == 0]
Out[3]: [False]
```

What I understood is `a % 2 == 0` evaluates to `True` or `False`.

So if it is True then that is equivalent to  1 and using list indices it's going to print `'is even'`.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int) and came to know `bool` is an instance of `int`.

So when used as in index `bool` evaluates to it's equivalent number i.e `0` or `1`.

**My question**

Based on intuition we can know whether it's going to be an `int` or `bool`

But how does Python know? Does it have any criteria when to use as `bool` and when to use as `int`? Anything from Python3 documentation would be appreiated.

Comment: You are not evaluating an int here but a conditional expression thus you are of course receiving a bool

Comment: Go ahead and run `False.real` and `True.real` and see what happens

Comment: @IanAuld False.real=0,True.real=1

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.x this is not guaranteed as it is possible for `True` and `False` to be reassigned. However, even if this happens, boolean `True` and boolean `False` are still properly returned for comparisons.

In Python 3.x True and False are keywords and will always be equal to `1` and `0`.

Under normal circumstances in Python 2, and always in Python 3:

`False` object is of type `bool` which is a subclass of `int`:

```
 object
   |
  int
   |
  bool
```

It is the only reason why in your example, `['zero', 'one'][False]` does work. It would not work with an object which is not a subclass of integer, because list indexing only works with integers, or objects that define the `__index__` method (thanks mark-dickinson).

**Edit:**

It is true of the current Python version, and of that of Python 3. The docs for Python 2.6 and the docs for Python 3 both say:

> There are two types of integers: [...] Integers (int) [...] Booleans (bool)
>   and in the boolean subsection:
>
> Booleans: These represent the truth values False and True [...] Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

So booleans are explicitly considered as integers in Python 2.6 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `bool` instances, `True` and `False`, are separate from the `int` instances, `0` and `1`. The thing is that the bools behave like integers in many contexts. Such as `True+True` which is 2. However if we check if they are the same object we see it is not: `True is 1`. On the other hand it is true that `True is True`. Here's an example which behaves like integers but are printed as True and False and compares differently with `is`.

```
class Bool(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'True' if self==1 else 'False'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-boolean-values