# Why does my Sieve of Eratosthenes work faster with integers than with booleans?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, boolean, cpython

I wrote a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes, which uses a list of ones and turns them into zeros if not prime, like so:

```
def eSieve(n): #Where m is fixed-length list of all integers up to n
    '''Creates a list of primes less than or equal to n'''
    m = [1]*(n+1)
    for i in xrange(2,int((n)**0.5)+1):
        if m[i]:
            for j in xrange(i*i,n+1,i):
                m[j]=0
    return [i for i in xrange(2,n) if m[i]]
```

I tested the speed it ran with `%timeit` and got:

```
#n: t
#10**1: 7 μs
#10**2: 26.6 μs
#10**3: 234 μs
#10**4: 2.46 ms
#10**5: 26.4 ms
#10**6: 292 ms
#10**7: 3.27 s
```

I assumed, if I changed `[1]` and `0` to booleans, it would run faster... but it does the opposite:

```
#n: t
#10**1: 7.31 μs
#10**2: 29.5 μs
#10**3: 297 μs
#10**4: 2.99 ms
#10**5: 29.9 ms
#10**6: 331 ms
#10**7: 3.7 s
```

Why are the booleans slower?

Comment: I suspect it's because boolean's subclass int: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int

Comment: The general way to answer questions like this for yourself is to compare the bytecode for the two versions.

Comment: Note that this question is specific to one particular implementation of Python, namely CPython.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: nope, it's how they are resolved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because `True` and `False` are looked up as globals in Python 2. The `0` and `1` literals are just constants, looked up by a quick array reference, while globals are *dictionary* lookups in the global namespace (falling through to the built-ins namespace):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     a = True
...     b = 1
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `True` value is looked up with the `LOAD_GLOBAL` bytecode, while the `1` literal value is copied to the stack with `LOAD_CONST`.

If you make `True` and `False` *locals* you can make them just as fast again:

```
def eSieve(n, True=True, False=False):
    m = [True]*(n+1)
    for i in xrange(2,int((n)**0.5)+1):
        if m[i]:
            for j in xrange(i*i,n+1,i):
                m[j]=False
    return [i for i in xrange(2,n) if m[i]]
```

Assigning `True` and `False` as default values to for arguments gives the function those names as locals, with the exact same values; again using a simplified version:

```
>>> def bar(True=True, False=False):
...     True == False
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (True)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (False)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the `LOAD_FAST` opcodes, now with indices just like the `LOAD_CONST` bytecodes; locals in a CPython function are stored in an array just like bytecode constants.

With that change, using booleans wins out, albeit by a small margin; my timings:

```
# n      integers  globals  locals
# 10**1  4.31 µs   4.2 µs   4.2 µs
# 10**2  17.1 µs   17.3 µs  16.5 µs
# 10**3  147 µs    158 µs   144 µs
# 10**4  1.5 ms    1.66 ms  1.48 ms
# 10**5  16.4 ms   18.2 ms  15.9 ms
# 10**6  190 ms    215 ms   189 ms   
# 10**7  2.21 s    2.47 s   2.18 s
```

The difference isn't really that much because Python booleans are just an `int` subclass.

Note that in Python 3, `True` and `False` have become keywords and can no longer be assigned to, making it possible to treat them just like integer literals.

Comment: Probably no need for the local `True`, since it's only used once.

Comment: You mean `[True]*(n+1)` will look it up `n+1` times? Shouldn't that just use it once when creating the `[True]` array, then the multiplication will use the value in the array rather than the variable?

Comment: @Barmar: each time the function is run by `%timeit` (which *repeatedly* measures it and averages the times) it'll do that lookup. Which, I now realise, makes very little difference to the average time. :-P

Comment: @Barmar: at any rate, it looks nicer and more consistent. Yeah, `True` is looked up just the once per function call, so the difference is going to be minimal.