# Finding the index of the element contains string in a list

Tags: python

For example, the list contains:

- 2 strings
- 1 int
- 1 bool
- 1 nested list

Example:

```
["string1", 34, True, "string2", [2,4,6]]
```

**Question:** How to find the index of those 2 strings in the list? (object-types in the list must be treated as unknown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use `isinstance()`**:

```
my_list = [True, 10.8, [1,2,3], False, True, "Hello", 12, "Sbioer", 2.5]

for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if isinstance(item, basestring):
        print i
```

**Output:**

```
5
7
```

However, if you want to check for **`int`** values, you will get bool-type item's indexes too because (quoting text from some other source):

> It is perfectly logical, if you were around when the bool type was
>   added to python (sometime around 2.2 or 2.3).
>
> Prior to introduction of an actual bool type, 0 and 1 were the
>   official representation for truth value, similar to C89. To avoid
>   unnecessarily breaking non-ideal but working code, the new bool type
>   needed to work just like 0 and 1. This goes beyond merely truth value,
>   but all integral operations. No one would recommend using a boolean
>   result in a numeric context, nor would most people recommend testing
>   equality to determine truth value, no one wanted to find out the hard
>   way just how much existing code is that way. Thus the decision to make
>   True and False masquerade as 1 and 0, respectively. This is merely a
>   historical artifact of the linguistic evolution.

So if you want to check for only **`int`** values just:

```
my_list = [True, 10.8, [1,2,3], False, True, "Hello", 12, "Sbioer", 2.5]

for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if isinstance(item, int) and not isinstance(item, bool):
        print i
```

Comment: `basestring` should be used in Python 2.x to include both `str` and `unicode` types!

Comment: You're welcome! However, it should be `isinstance(item, str)` for 3.x, and `isinstance(item, basestring)` in 2.x.

Comment: thanks, but when l replace str with int and the index for is wrong

Comment: It's not wrong. bool type is subtype of int. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int

Comment: Calling `index()` on the list whilst already iterating over it is inefficient. Iterate over `enumerate(my_list)` instead.

Comment: Wow! l learned a lot! Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this the right answer to your question then? :)

Comment: @ Andrés Pérez-Albela H.  Yes!!  :)

Comment: Great! Then, please set it as the answer to your question clicking on the check mark sign.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is named `s`, then the following will work:

```
[i for i in range(len(s)) if type(s[i]) == str]
```

If you want to handle unicode strings, then you can change it to:

```
[i for i in range(len(s)) if isinstance(s[i], basestring)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [**`enumerate()`**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [**`isinstance()`**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) to get the index of the string items:

```
l = [1, True, 'Hello', [1, 3, False, 'nested'], 'Bye']

for i, item in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(item, basestring):   # Python 2. Use (str, bytes) instead of basestring for Python 3
        print i
```

Produces this output:

```
2
4
```

Note that this does not descend into the nested list; you will want to use recursion to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with `type()` function. Have a try with the following code.

```
   l = [1,'abc', 'def', [1,2,3], True]
    ans = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if type(l[i]) == str:
            ans.append(i)

    print ans
```