# Effect of tilde on booleans — why ~True is -2 & ~False is -1 in Python?

Tags: python, boolean

I found that `~True` is `-2` and `~False` is `-1`. Why is this?

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) says that `~` inverts all the bits. Why isn't `~True` is `False` and `~False` is `True`?

### Reasoning attempts

My attempt to explain these:

`True` is `+1`, and the bits of `+1` are inverted. `+` is inverted to `-`.
`1` in two-digit binary is `01`, so inverted bits: `10`, ie `2`. So result is `-2`.

`False` is `+0`, `+` is inverted to `-`, `0` in two-digit binary is `00`, all the bits inverted, `11`, which is `3` - it should be `1`.

### Sources

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502832/8565438) paints a more complicated picture:

> A list full of Trues only contains 4- or 8-byte references to the one
> canonical True object.

[The PyTables User’s Guide](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/datatypes.html) says:

> bool: Boolean (true/false) types. Supported precisions: 8 (default)
> bits.

*These don't support the simplistic (and apparently wrong) reasoning above.*

Comment: Did you look at [the canonical reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=bitwise#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations)? *"The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`."*

Comment: ~1 is -2 and ~0 is -1 using two's-complement signed integers.

Comment: Alright, thanks, that's helpful; I didn't.

Comment: Alright, thanks! noted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'd use the `not` operator to invert Boolean values (`not True == False`, and vice versa). Now if Booleans are stored as 8-bit integers, the following happens:

`True` is 0000 0001. Hence `~True` yields 1111 1110, which is -2 in two's-complement representation.

`False` is 0000 0000. Hence `~False` yields 1111 1111, which is -1.

Comment: Would you add some details on why  1111 1110 is -2? As I understand 1110 is 2, but why? why not 0010 is 2?

Comment: @zabop `0010` *is* 2. `1110` is **minus** 2, if you only have four bits and you're using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: In two's complement inverting the sign involves: "flip the bits and add 1". If the first bit is set, the number is negative, else positive. Now let me try this with 1110. The first bit is set (where first is the leftmost bit in this case), thus it is negative. The positive number is then (flip the bits and add one) 0001 + 1 = 0010 ( = 2 in decimal representation)