# Most efficient way to convert values of column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, boolean

I have a a pd.DataFrame that looks like:

[image]

I want to create a cutoff on the values to push them into binary digits, my cutoff in this case is `0.85`.  I want the resulting dataframe to look like:

[image]

The script I wrote to do this is easy to understand but for large datasets it is inefficient.  I'm sure Pandas has some way of taking care of these types of transformations.

**Does anyone know of an efficient way to convert a column of floats to a column of integers using a threshold?**

My extremely naive way of doing such a thing:

```
DF_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([list("abcde"),list("pqrst"),[0.12,0.23,0.93,0.86,0.33]]).T,columns=["c1","c2","value"])
DF_want = pd.DataFrame(np.array([list("abcde"),list("pqrst"),[0,0,1,1,0]]).T,columns=["c1","c2","value"])


threshold = 0.85

#Empty dataframe to append rows
DF_naive = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(DF_test.shape[0]):
    #Get first 2 columns
    first2cols = list(DF_test.ix[i][:-1])
    #Check if value is greater than threshold
    binary_value = [int((bool(float(DF_test.ix[i][-1]) > threshold)))]
    #Create series object
    SR_row = pd.Series( first2cols + binary_value,name=i)
    #Add to empty dataframe container
    DF_naive = DF_naive.append(SR_row)
#Relabel columns
DF_naive.columns = DF_test.columns
DF_naive.head()
#the sample DF_want
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to set your desired value based on a boolean condition:

```
In [18]:
DF_test['value'] = np.where(DF_test['value'] > threshold, 1,0)
DF_test

Out[18]:
  c1 c2  value
0  a  p      0
1  b  q      0
2  c  r      1
3  d  s      1
4  e  t      0
```

Note that because your data is a heterogenous np array the 'value' column contains strings rather than floats:

```
In [58]:
DF_test.iloc[0]['value']

Out[58]:
'0.12'
```

So you'll need to convert the `dtype` to `float` first: `DF_test['value'] = DF_test['value'].astype(float)`

You can compare the timings:

```
In [16]:
%timeit np.where(DF_test['value'] > threshold, 1,0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop

In [17]:
%%timeit
DF_naive = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(DF_test.shape[0]):
    #Get first 2 columns
    first2cols = list(DF_test.ix[i][:-1])
    #Check if value is greater than threshold
    binary_value = [int((bool(float(DF_test.ix[i][-1]) > threshold)))]
    #Create series object
    SR_row = pd.Series( first2cols + binary_value,name=i)
    #Add to empty dataframe container
    DF_naive = DF_naive.append(SR_row)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.3 ms per loop
```

the `np.where` version is over 100x faster, admittedly your code is doing a lot of unnecessary stuff but you get the point

Comment: Thank you * 1000

Answer (score 1):

Since [`bool` is a subclass of `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int), i.e. `True == 1` and `False == 0`, you can convert a Boolean series to its integer form:

```
DF_test['value'] = (DF_test['value'] > threshold).astype(int)
```

Generally, including most uses in computation or indexing, the `int` conversion is not necessary and you may wish to forego it altogether.