# How do I create a column based on a certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe -

```
df = {'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
```

How do I create a column 'B' that returns 1 if the value in column A is equal to 5 or above or 0 if the value in column A is below 5.

Comment: Use `df['B'] = df['A'].ge(5).astype(int)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to convert values of column in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639588/most-efficient-way-to-convert-values-of-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use the list comprehension together with if statement, just as below:

```
df['B'] = [1 if x >= 5 else 0 for x in df.A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np
df['B']=np.where(df['A'].lt(5), 0, df['A'])
```