# Logical indexing with lists

Tags: python, list

I have a program I'm looking through and with this section

```
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
temp[temp!=1]=0
print temp
```

Which if run gives the result:

```
[1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I need help understanding what is going on in this code that leads to this result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`temp` in your example is a `list`, which clearly is not equal to 1. Thus the expression

```
 temp[temp != 1] = 0
```

is actually

```
temp[True] = 0  # or, since booleans are also integers in CPython
temp[1] = 0
```

Convert `temp` to a NumPy array to get the broadcasting behaviour you need

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> temp = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> temp[temp != 1] = 0
>>> temp 
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 8):

As Already explained you are setting the second element using the result of comparing to a list which returns True/1 as [bool is a subclass of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int). You have a list not a numpy array so you need to iterate over it if you want to change it which you can do with a list comprehension using *if/els*e logic:

```
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
temp[:] = [0 if ele != 1 else ele for ele in temp ]
```

Which will give you:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or using a *generator expression*:

```
temp[:] = (0 if ele != 1 else ele for ele in temp)
```

Answer (score 4):

If NumPy is not an option, use a list comprehension to build a new list.

```
>>> temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [int(x == 1) for x in temp]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```