# Clarification needed while accessing python - tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = True
print(('A','B')[a == False])
```

Could you please explain me in detail, preferably line-by-line what will be the output?

Comment: `False` is actually just an integer 0. `True` is just an integer 1. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You'll learn better if you work it out by yourself, step by step. Figure out what the value of each part of the expression will be, then combine them.

Comment: No.  Instead, please explain exactly what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Doing that initial investigation is *your* task before you post here.  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical indexing with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721383/logical-indexing-with-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is confusing in part because it relies on dynamic type conversion.  This is not particularly well written code.

```
a = True 
idx = (a == False) # False
("A", "B")[idx] # idx gets converted to int(False) -> 0
("A", "B")[0] # -> "A"
```

The tricky part is that `False` when cast as an `int` type is equal to `0`, which is then used as an index for the tuple ("A", "B").  This is bad practice and generally confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1. `a` is set to `True`, and Python's `bool` is a subclass of the `int` type, so `a` can be interpreted as `1`.
2. (Omitting the `print` statement because that shouldn't need explaining), a tuple `("A", "B")` whose indices are `0` and `1` respectively, is indexed at the result of the boolean expression `a == False`. The result of the expression is `False` since `a` is `True`, so `a == False` is `False` and therefore is interpreted as `0`, so the tuple is indexed at index `0`, which prints `"A"`.