# What does i-(i>0) do in for neighbor in active[i-(i>0):i+1]:

Tags: python, for-loop

I saw some example python code:

```
for neighbor in active[i-(i>0):i+1]:
```

and just curious what `i-(i>0)` here do?

Answer (score 1):

`(i>0)` is a condition that is `True` when `i>0` and thus yields 1.

You can think of it also as `active[i-{1 if i > 0, else 0}:i+1]:`

*A good comment by @Mad Physicist: bools are a subclass of int where {True,False} == {1,0}. You can find more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8169001/3512538)*

Quote from the link above about this code:

> No one would recommend using a boolean result in a numeric context

Comment: Probably should mention that bools are a subclass of `int`: `True == 1` and  `False == 0`

Comment: `{1 if i > 0, else 0}`: no comma here. Actually, `int(i>0)` is a better way type cast.