# Understanding the use of non Boolean operators on Booleans

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic

I have been trying out the use of `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` operators on booleans and I do not understand the strange output results I am getting:

**First example using the `+`:**

```
>>> a = True
>>> b = False
>>> a + b
1
>>> a + a
2 
>>> b + b
0
```

It is clear I am not getting boolean outputs and sure enough:

```
>>> type(a + a)
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

**Second example using `-`:**

```
>>> a - b
1
>>> a - a
0
>>>b - b
0
```

All integers once again.

**Third example using `*`:**

```
>>> a * a
1
>>> a * b 
0
>>> b * b
0
>>>
```

**And finally using `/` (which returned an error):**

```
>>> a / a
1.0
>>> a / b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> b / b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>>
```

Interestingly:

```
>>> type(a / a)
<class 'float'>
>>>
```

Returns a float.

What is going on.  Why am I getting these integer and float output when using non-boolean operatons and not some Boolean operator as I would expect?

Comment: It's because `bool` is a subclass of `int`. `True` has a value of 1, while `False` has a value of 0. Related questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Comment: the question is slightly different. OP is wondering why results return an `integer` when they could return a `boolean`. `boolean` _could_ be a subclass and still return a boolean type when it fits the range (ok it would be confusing)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's not how I read the question, but I wouldn't be opposed to the question being reopened. It's not a great dupe anyway.

Comment: I agree on "not a great dupe" :) But I don't like using my gold badge powers to reopen against someone else.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I disagree (and am somewhat unhappy) with this duplicate, but I will trust your judgement.   So it's as basic as `1 + 1 = 2`

Comment: @Simon If your question is just "Why can I do math with booleans", then I think it's enough to explain that booleans are a subclass of ints (so in that case I'd say the duplicate is appropriate). But if, as Jean-François Fabre said, you're asking "Why does this return an int instead of a boolean?", then the question should be reopened. FWIW, I've cast a reopen vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean` is a subclass of `int`. `False` and `True` have resp. 0 and 1 values.

When performing an addition, the addition method of `int` is used, boolean doesn't redefine either `__add__` or `__sub__` (or mul or div...) so the result is of `int` type, even if `False + True` or `False + False` could fit in a boolean type (an addition method which would return an integer or a boolean depending on the range would be a bit weird).

```
>>> bool.__add__ is int.__add__
True
>>> bool.__sub__ is int.__sub__
True
```

and `type(a / a)` is `float` because of python 3 floating point division even between integers. If you need `int`, do `type(a // a)`

Answer (score 1):

Basically True is equal to the integer 1 and False is equal to the integer 0.
This is because Boolean is a subclass of int.

You can get these values by converting the bools into ints:

```
int(True)
int(False)
```