# How do we use 'and' operator in array indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing, iteration

I found one code that used `A[i][j] += min(A[i - 1][j and j - 1:j + 2])`
I tried similar implementation as shown below which gave me unexpected results.Can anyone explain me? I am not able to understand how 'and' is interpreted in such situations.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

print(a[0 and 3:4]) #[1, 2, 3, 4]

print(a[1 and 3:4]) #[4]

print(a[1 and 3:6]) #[4, 5, 6] 

print(a[0 and 3:6]) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(a[2 and 3:6]) #[4, 5, 6]
```

edit : in a[0 and 3:4] it includes elements from 0 to 3 but if I use a[1 and 3:4] it gives only 3rd element whereas I expect elements from 1 to 3

Comment: What do you mean by _unexpected results_?

Comment: edited. Please check

Comment: `0 and 3` is `0` because `0` is falsey. `1 and 3` is `3` because `1` is truthy. See dupe target.

Comment: Fun fact: In case you don't know: True is also an integer, i.e, 1 . [bool inherits int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int). But be careful about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has higher precedence than slice `:` operator.

Your expressions works as,

```
a[0 and 3:4] --> a[(0 and 3):4] --> a[0:4] --> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Yeah I got that now. But what in case of 'and' between two non-zero integers?

Comment: non-zero integers are non-false values so between two non-zero values, the second one will be used. `-1 and -5` --> `-5`

Comment: oh thanks. clears all confusions.

Comment: @KaranShah And now that you know how it works, don't ever use it like this ;-)

Comment: hehe but it is fun XD @jarmod

Answer (score 1):

You are simply comparing integer values by "and" in your case - not the values behind the index values. If you compare anything with 0, you get 0. In all the other cases, you get the value of the second integer (Maybe not for every python interpreter).