# Count the number of digits in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

**Question**

I have an email_alias column and I'd like to find the number of integers in that column (per row) in another column using Python. So far I can only count the total number of numbers in the entire column.

**Attempt**

I tried: `df['count_numbers'] = sum(c.isdigit() for c in df['email_alias'])`

**Example**:

```
email_alias       count_numbers
thisisatest111      3
testnumber2         1
```

Comment: Presumably you tried something from your research around this problem; what was the issue with your implementation?

Comment: I tried: df['count_numbers'] = sum(c.isdigit() for c in df['email_alias'])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a custom python function to the column. I don't think there's a vectorized way. `sum()` here takes advantage of the fact that [bools are a subclass of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int) so all `True` values are equal to `1`.

```
import pandas as pd

def count_digits(string):
    return sum(item.isdigit() for item in string)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['thisisatest111', 'testnumber2']})
df['counts'] = df['a'].apply(count_digits)
```

Your approach of:

```
df['count_numbers'] = sum(c.isdigit() for c in df['email_alias'])
```

could not work because `df['count_numbers'] =` is an assignment to *every value in that column*. Here, `apply` implicitly iterates over the rows (but in Python time, so it's not vectorized). Then again, most of the `.str` accessor methods of Pandas are, too, despite the syntax suggesting it will go faster than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this might be the simplest solution.

```
df['count_numbers'] = df['email_alias'].str.count('\d')
```

Comment: by far the most elegant answer

Comment: To avoid getting the warning
`DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d` simply write `r'\d'` i.e., give raw string.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you code and get the same result in one line (idea from roganjosh's answer):

```
df["count_numbers"] = df["email_alias"].apply(lambda x: sum(c.isdigit() for c in x))
```