# Bool values in pandas DataFrame converted to ints whilst applying function to multiply numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Whilst applying the below function I have bool values converted to integers.

What am I missing?

```
import pandas as pd

def multi(x):
    if isinstance(x, (float, int)):
        return x * 10
    return x

print(pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [True, False]}).applymap(func=multi))
```

Ouput:

```
    a
0  10
1   0
```

Expected:

```
       a
0   True
1   False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>>
```

`True` is actually `1`!

And `False` is actually `0`, so you're kinda attempting this approach strangely.

To fix it, use `type`:

```
def multi(x):
    if type(x) in (float, int)):
        return x * 10
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Booleans are treated as integers (1, 0) when you're multiplying with a numeric. So when you do

```
True * 10 #(= 1 * 10)
```

the output is

```
10
```

Similarly,

```
False * 10 #(= 0 * 10)
```

will equal 0

This is because Boolean is a subclass of int. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int)