# Why does (False + True) return an integer in python

Tags: python

```
print(False + True)
```

Why does this return an integer `1`

Is there any explanation?

Also `print((int(False + True) == (False + True)) )`

returns True, so this means that True + False is indeed an integer ?

Comment: This question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int

Comment: In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively. The Python documentation

Comment: also related https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017/4744341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the python 3 docs [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Booleans (bool)
>
> These represent the truth values False and True. The
> two objects representing the values False and True are the only
> Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type,
> and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in
> almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a
> string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

So yes, they are a subtype of integer and behave mostly like them.

(Python 2 operates differently, but it is end-of-life so I am not adding its rules)

Answer (score 3):

`bool` is a subclass of `int`:

```
>>> bool.mro()
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

`print(False + True)` returns 1 because
`int(True)` = 1 and `int(False)` = 0

True has a value of 1 and False has a value of 0. They are binary values. You can use them interchangeably with their integer equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Not Integers  per say, they are binary digits {True:1, False:0}

Comment: What are "binary digits"? Python doesn't seem to have a concept of binary digits. Also, `True.__sizeof__() == 28`, so `True` definitely doesn't occupy one bit, like a "binary digit" would.