# Boolean "True" is not printing from set in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
c= {1,3,5,89.07, True, "Night", 1,3}
print(c)
```

when I run this code, the output I received was,
**{1, 3, 'Night', 5, 89.07}**

but when I replaced the "True" bool with False, the output was,
**{False,1, 3, 'Night', 5, 89.07}**

So, why it is not giving "True" bool in first case ?

Comment: `print({ 1, True })` outputs `{1}` and `print({ 0, False })` outputs `0`. Strange.

Comment: No. I am talking about set in python.

Comment: but for dictionaries we use ":" to specify the keys and values. Here the scenario is different. Its really strange.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a similar effect is observed for `0`:

```py
>>> print({ 1, True })
{1}
>>> print({ 0, False })
{0}
```

This seems to be because in Python [`bool` is a subclass of `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8169001/4608364), and often `False` acts like `0` and `True` like `1`:

```py
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> False + True
1
>>> False * 100
0
>>> 8 ** False
1
```

It's even the case that `False == 0` and `True == 1`!

So in your case because `1` is already in your set, adding `True` to it makes no difference. But if you add `False` you get a new element.

Comment: Yeah, now I got it. Thank you Quelklef. It was really helpful.

Comment: If you find that this answer solved your question. Please mark it as solved, there is a check mark next to the answer. @Quelklef nice explanation.