# Adding the number 1 to a set has no effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I cannot add the integer number `1` to an existing set. In an interactive shell, this is what I am doing:

```
>>> st = {'a', True, 'Vanilla'}
>>> st
{'a', True, 'Vanilla'}
>>> st.add(1)
>>> st
{'a', True, 'Vanilla'}   # Here's the problem; there's no 1, but anything else works
>>> st.add(2)
>>> st
{'a', True, 'Vanilla', 2}
```

This question was posted two months ago, but I believe it was misunderstood.
I am using Python 3.2.3.

Comment: Why would you try to store truth-values, strings, and numbers in a single set?  What problem were you trying to solve?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> 1 == True
True
```

I believe your problem is that `1` and `True` are the same value, so 1 is "already in the set".

```
>>> st
{'a', True, 'Vanilla'}
>>> 1 in st
True
```

In mathematical operations `True` is itself treated as `1`:

```
>>> 5 + True
6
>>> True * 2
2
>>> 3. / (True + True)
1.5
```

Though True is a bool and 1 is an int:

```
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
```

Because `1 in st` returns True, I think you shouldn't have any problems with it.  It is a very strange result though.  If you're interested in further reading, @Lattyware points to [PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) which explains this issue in depth.

Comment: Interesting that `1` and `True` are considered equal when their representation is totally different.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree, I'd almost call this a flaw?  I would love to hear Guido's explanation of why this happens.

Comment: I suppose it's no different than `1 == 1.0`. It sure looks odd though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169001/why-is-bool-a-subclass-of-int/8169072#8169072

Comment: It's a long-disputed issue - a lot of people wanted it changed for Python 3. Originally there was no separate `bool` type in Python. Read [PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) for why it was done like this.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Could you please express (maybe in a different answer) what operations happen "under the hood" when we call `1 in {'a',True}`, which eventually return `True`? As for me, it's not very trivial.

Comment: @ovgolovin:  For historical (note i'm not saying "for logical") reasons, `bool` inherits from `int`.  Since `True` has a value of 1, 1 is considered a member of the set `{'a',True}`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski As I understand, it happens the following way: 1)`hash(1)` is calculated to be equal to `1`; 2)this hash value is searched in the set; 3)the corresponding bin is found; 4) there is a value `True` in that bin which happens to be `1==True`; 5) `1 in {True}` returns `True`. Correct? :)

Comment: I also do not like the fact that `1 == True`, because it is simply confusing.  However, it is the implementation tradeof, possibly also herigage of the C language.  The major argument probably is that makin `True` not equal to `1` would break older Python code.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, though I'm not certain, that because `hash(1) == hash(True)` and also `1 == True` that they are considered the same elements by the `set`.  I don't believe that should be the case, as `1 is True` is `False`, but I believe it explains why you can't add it.

Comment: The `is` result is an implementation detail and should never be relied upon. `==` is the proper test.

Comment: +1 because the hash equivalency is key here, but I agree with Mark that what you said about `is` isn't really relevant.  `1 is 1` could be `False` and not violate anything in documentation (and something like `300 is (299+1)` probably will give you `False`).

Answer (score 1):

`1` is equivalent to `True` as `1 == True` returns true. As a result the insertion of `1` is rejected as a set cannot have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some link if anyone is interested in further study.

[Is it Pythonic to use bools as ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints/3175293#3175293)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/1355722

Answer (score 0):

We have to use a list if you want to have items with the same hash.If you're absolutely sure your set needs to be able to contain both True and 1.0, I'm pretty sure you'll have to define your own custom class, probably as a thin wrapper around dict.
As in many languages, Python's set type is just a thin wrapper around dict where we're only interested in the keys.

Ex:

```
st = {'a', True, 'Vanilla'}

list_st = []

for i in st:
    list_st.append(i)
    
list_st.append(1)

for i in list_st:
    print(f'The hash of {i} is {hash(i)}')
```

produces

```
The hash of True is 1
The hash of Vanilla is -6149594130004184476
The hash of a is 8287428602346617974
The hash of 1 is 1

[Program finished]
```