# Why does Python produce different sets from identical input?

Tags: python, set

Condider the following example:

```
>>> {1, True}
set([True])
>>
>>> {True, 1}
set([1])
```

Why is the set represented differently, depending on the order of the elements?

Comment: Because booleans are a subclass of `int` and `True == 1` (and `False == 0`). This is a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017) Hard to searh for the duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters One of the examples can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419918/adding-the-number-1-to-a-set-has-no-effect/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `1` and `True` are equal to each other:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> 1 == True
True
```

The set retains one element from each equality class.

Answer (score 0):

bool is subclass of int class

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True

>>> True+1
2
>>> True == 1
True
```