# number of values in a list greater than a certain number

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers and I want to get the number of times a number appears in a list that meets a certain criteria. I can use a list comprehension (or a list comprehension in a function) but I am wondering if someone has a shorter way.

```
# list of numbers
j=[4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]
#list comprehension of values of j > 5
x = [i for i in j if i>5]
#value of x
len(x)

#or function version
def length_of_list(list_of_numbers, number):
     x = [i for i in list_of_numbers if j > number]
     return len(x)
length_of_list(j, 5)
```

is there an even more condensed version?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> j = [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5]
>>> sum(i > 5 for i in j)
3
```

It might initially seem strange to add `True` to `True` this way, but I don't think it's unpythonic; after all, `bool` [is a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175293/577088) of `int` in all versions since 2.3:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Comment: @jamylak, why is this better than Greg Hewgill's?  While it is interesting and correct, it seems much less intuitive and less obvious for someone else reading the code.

Comment: @TJD Didn't say it was better but I like it more.

Comment: @senderle: (Greg's *previous* deleted answer. I added a new answer that will work. :)

Comment: `sum(1 for i in j if i > 5)` would be a bit more explicit, if that is intended :) The `sum(1 for ... if ...)` can also be hidden away in a `count` function.

Comment: @NiklasB., ah, of course you're right -- a conditional expression isn't even necessary.

Answer (score 24):

You can create a smaller intermediate result like this:

```
>>> j = [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5]
>>> len([1 for i in j if i > 5])
3
```

Comment: Or `sum(1 for i in j if i > 5)` so you don't have to load the list into memory.

Answer (score 16):

if you are otherwise using numpy, you can save a few strokes, but i dont think it gets much faster/compact than senderle's answer.

```
import numpy as np
j = np.array(j)
sum(j > i)
```

Answer (score 4):

A (somewhat) different way:

`reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + (1 if x > 5 else 0), j, 0)`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using NumPy (as in ludaavic's answer), for large arrays you'll probably want to use NumPy's `sum` function rather than Python's builtin `sum` for a significant speedup -- e.g., a >1000x speedup for 10 million element arrays on my laptop:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ten_million = 10 * 1000 * 1000
>>> x, y = (np.random.randn(ten_million) for _ in range(2))
>>> %timeit sum(x > y)  # time Python builtin sum function
1 loops, best of 3: 24.3 s per loop
>>> %timeit (x > y).sum()  # wow, that was really slow! time NumPy sum method
10 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.sum(x > y)  # time NumPy sum function
10 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop
```

(above uses IPython's `%timeit` "magic" for timing)

Answer (score 3):

Different way of counting by using bisect module:

```
>>> from bisect import bisect
>>> j = [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5]
>>> j.sort()
>>> b = 5
>>> index = bisect(j,b) #Find that index value
>>> print len(j)-index
3
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll add a map and filter version because why not.

```
sum(map(lambda x:x>5, j))
sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x:x>5, j))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this using function:

```py
l = [34,56,78,2,3,5,6,8,45,6]  
print ("The list : " + str(l))   
def count_greater30(l):  
    count = 0  
    for i in l:  
        if i > 30:  
            count = count + 1.  
    return count
print("Count greater than 30 is : " + str(count)).  
count_greater30(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit longer but the detailed solution for beginners:

```
from functools import reduce 
from statistics import mean

two_dim_array = [[1, 5, 7, 3, 2], [2, 4 ,1 ,6, 8]]

# convert two dimensional array to one dimensional array 
one_dim_array = reduce(list.__add__, two_dim_array)

arithmetic_mean = mean(one_dim_array)

exceeding_count = sum(i > arithmetic_mean for i in one_dim_array)
```