# fast way to do number of items in a list below a certain threshold

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to quickly check how many items in a list are below a series of thresholds, similar to doing what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543303/number-of-values-in-a-list-greater-than-a-certain-number) but a lot of times. The point of this is to do some diagnostics on a machine learning model that are a little more in depth than what is built in to sci-kit learn (ROC curves, etc.).

Imagine `preds` is a list of predictions (probabilities between 0 and 1). In reality, I will have over 1 million of them, which is why I'm trying to speed this up.

This creates some fake scores, normally distributed between 0 and 1.

```
fake_preds = [np.random.normal(0, 1) for i in range(1000)]
fake_preds = [(pred + np.abs(min(fake_preds)))/max(fake_preds + np.abs(min(fake_preds))) for pred in fake_preds]
```

Now, the way I am doing this is to loop through 100 threshold levels and check how many predictions are lower at any given threshold:

```
thresholds = [round(n,2) for n in np.arange(0.01, 1.0, 0.01)]
thresh_cov = [sum(fake_preds < thresh) for thresh in thresholds]
```

This takes about 1.5 secs for 10k (less time than generating the fake predictions) but you can imagine it takes a lot longer with a lot more predictions. And I have to do this a few thousand times to compare a bunch of different models.

Any thoughts on a way to make that second code block faster? I'm thinking there must be a way to order the predictions to make it easier for the computer to check the thresholds (similar to indexing in SQL-like scenario) but I can't figure out any other way than `sum(fake_preds < thresh)` to check them, and that doesn't take advantage of any indexing or ordering.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `fake_preds < thresh` what does this mean?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: It's a `numpy`-ism; it's creating a boolean array of values which pass the `thresh` and those which don't.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ah, that's really fancy.

Comment: I looked at [`numpy.digitize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) which I thought might be promising, but given what you actually want to do I don't think it actually helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #1**

You can sort `predictions` array and then use [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) or [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html), like so -

```
np.searchsorted(np.sort(fake_preds), thresholds, 'right')

np.digitize(thresholds, np.sort(fake_preds))
```

If you don't mind mutating `predictions` array, sort in-place with : `fake_preds.sort()` and then use `fake_preds` in place of `np.sort(fake_preds)`. This should be much more performant as we would be avoiding the use of any extra memory there.

**Method #2**

Now, with the thresholds being `100` from `0` to `1`, those thresholds would be multiples of `0.01`. Thus, we can simply digitize with a scaling up of `100` for each of them and converting them to `ints`, which could be pretty straight-forwardly fed as `bins` to `np.bincount`. Then, to get or desired result, use `cumsum`, like so -

```
np.bincount((fake_preds*100).astype(int),minlength=99)[:99].cumsum()
```

### Benchmarking

Approaches -

```
def searchsorted_app(fake_preds, thresholds):
    return np.searchsorted(np.sort(fake_preds), thresholds, 'right')

def digitize_app(fake_preds, thresholds):
    return np.digitize(thresholds, np.sort(fake_preds) )

def bincount_app(fake_preds, thresholds):
    return np.bincount((fake_preds*100).astype(int),minlength=99)[:99].cumsum()
```

Runtime test and verification on `10000` elements -

```
In [210]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: fake_preds = np.random.rand(10000)
     ...: thresholds = [round(n,2) for n in np.arange(0.01, 1.0, 0.01)]
     ...: thresh_cov = [sum(fake_preds < thresh) for thresh in thresholds]
     ...: 

In [211]: print np.allclose(thresh_cov, searchsorted_app(fake_preds, thresholds))
     ...: print np.allclose(thresh_cov, digitize_app(fake_preds, thresholds))
     ...: print np.allclose(thresh_cov, bincount_app(fake_preds, thresholds))
     ...: 
True
True
True

In [214]: %timeit [sum(fake_preds < thresh) for thresh in thresholds]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.43 s per loop

In [215]: %timeit searchsorted_app(fake_preds, thresholds)
     ...: %timeit digitize_app(fake_preds, thresholds)
     ...: %timeit bincount_app(fake_preds, thresholds)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 535 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.9 µs per loop
```

That's a **`2,700x+`** speedup for `searchsorted` and **`57,000x+`** for `bincount` one! With larger datasets, the gap between `bincount` and `searchsorted` one is bound to increase, as `bincount` doesn't need to sort.

Comment: I'm really starting to think this should be the accepted answer. You've improved this speed significantly since your first answer, I just threw my hat in the ring :)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that my approach does not give identical binning behaviour to the Python approach due to rounding? I achieve the same _behaviour_ but I cannot get the bins to match. I also commented to OP in my answer that this answer improves on mine.

Comment: `bincount` fails for me with a list, so `%timeit np.array(fake_preds)` gives `50.4 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`. It's much faster, but requires the overhead of making the array. I could use `timeit` on your other methods without that overhead.

Comment: @roganjosh Well I assumed `fake_preds` to be an array, because otherwise `[sum(fake_preds < thresh) for thresh in thresholds]` won't work, as `fake_preds < thresh` would just be a scalar, with `thresh` being a scalar.

Comment: That's a good point - in the question it comes out as a list but I didn't piece the mismatch together :)

Comment: per @roganjosh request I've switched this to the accepted answer. It is a significant speed up. Thank you both! In terms of the binning question, for my case, the bins did _not_ need to match exactly. I just needed to replicate the behavior. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

`thresh_cov = np.histogram(fake_preds, len(thresholds))[0].cumsum()`

From `timeit`, I'm getting:

```
%timeit my_cov = np.histogram(fake_preds, len(thresholds))[0].cumsum()
169 µs ± 6.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit thresh_cov = [sum(fake_preds < thresh) for thresh in thresholds]
172 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: this is great and super simple! Thank you! My test on 1.5m went from 11s to 0.0s

Comment: @seth127 You're welcome. I've just done some tests and there's a _slight_ difference in how it's performing the binning. Although they, in principle, do the same thing, you will not get identical bins between the two approaches. I'm trying to find how to make them identical. I think it may be due to your rounding.

Comment: @seth127 `thresh_cov = np.histogram(fake_preds, thresholds, range=(0.01, 1.0))[0].cumsum()` will get the bins aligned better but there still seems to be a rounding issue so the bins will still be misaligned. Is it important that both methods give identical results or is it just the approach you're interested in? I don't like leaving it like this but I can't seem to get both approaches to give exactly the same binning behaviour.

Comment: @seth127 also note that Divakar has managed to improve on my speed significantly since the initial answer given and his approach does give identical binning behaviour.

Comment: Well few issues - I think you were needed to use thresholds array there and also I think you need to put in the last bin of `1.0`. Hence : `thresholds_ext = np.r_[thresholds, 1.0]`; `np.histogram(fake_preds, thresholds_ext)[0].cumsum()`. But, again  since `histogram` uses  the `rightmost edge`, that's probably messing up too.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape `thresholds` here to enable broadcasting.  First, here a few possible changes to your creation of `fake_preds` and `thresholds` that get rid of loops.

```
np.random.seed(123)
fake_preds = np.random.normal(size=1000)
fake_preds = (fake_preds + np.abs(fake_preds.min())) \
           / (np.max(fake_preds + np.abs((fake_preds.min()))))
thresholds = np.linspace(.01, 1, 100)
```

Then what you want to do is accomplishable in 1 line:

```
print(np.sum(np.less(fake_preds, np.tile(thresholds, (1000,1)).T), axis=1))
[  2   2   2   2   2   2   5   5   6   7   7  11  11  11  15  18  21  26
  28  34  40  48  54  63  71  77  90 100 114 129 143 165 176 191 206 222
 240 268 288 312 329 361 392 417 444 479 503 532 560 598 615 648 671 696
 710 726 747 768 787 800 818 840 860 877 891 902 912 919 928 942 947 960
 965 970 978 981 986 987 988 991 993 994 995 995 995 997 997 997 998 998
 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999]
```

Walkthrough:

`fake_preds` has shape (1000,1).  You need to manipulate `thresholds` into a shape that is compatible for broadcasting with this.  (See [general broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules).)

A broadcastable second shape would be

```
print(np.tile(thresholds, (1000,1)).T.shape)
# (100, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore 
thresh_cov = [percentileofscore (fake_preds, thresh) for thresh in thresholds]
```

Option 2:
same as above, but sort the list first

Option 3:
Insert your thresholds into the list, sort the list, find the indices of your thresholds. Note that if you have a quicksort algorithm, you can optimize it for your purposes by making your thresholds the pivots and terminating the sort once you've partitioned everything according to the thresholds.

Option 4:
Building on the above: Put your thresholds in a binary tree, then for each item in the list, compare it to the thresholds in a binary search. You can either do it item by item, or split the list into subsets at each step.