# Python Bool and int comparison and indexing on list with boolean values

Tags: python, list, indexing, boolean

Indexing on list with boolean values works fine.
Though the index should be an integer.

Following is what I tried in console:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> 
>>> l[False]
1
>>> l[True]
2
>>> l[False + True]
2
>>> l[False + 2*True]
3
>>> 
>>> l['0']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
```

When I tried `l['0']` it printed error that int type expected in indices and that is obvious.
Then, even the type of `'True'` and `'False'` being `Bool`, indexing on the list works fine and automatically converts it to int type and performs the operation.

Please explain what is going on internally.
I am posting question for the first time, so please forgive me for any mistake.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What's going on is that booleans actually *are* integers.  True is 1 and False is 0.  Bool is a subtype of int.

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

So it's not converting them to integers, it's just using them as integers.

(Bools are ints for historical reasons.  Before a bool type existed in Python, people used the integer 0 to mean false and 1 to mean true.  So when they added a bool type, they made the boolean values integers in order to maintain backward compatibility with old code that used these integer values.  See for instance http://www.peterbe.com/plog/bool-is-int .)

```
>>> help(True)
Help on bool object:

class bool(int)
 |  bool(x) -> bool
 |  
 |  Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
 |  The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
 |  The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
```

Comment: +1, I learned something. Did not know `bool` was a subclass of `int`.

Comment: I had just gone through this post too [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints/3175293#3175293)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Python *used* to lack booleans, we just used integers, 0 for `False` and any other integer for `True`. So when booleans were added to the language, the values `False` and `True`, can be treated as the integer values `0` and `1` still by the interpreter, to help backwards compatibility. Internally, `bool` is a sub-class of `int`.

In other words, the following equations are True:

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

and as you found out:

```
>>> True * 3
3
```

This doesn't extend to strings however.

Answer (score 2):

> ...Booleans are a subtype of plain integers.

[Source](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

As you can see, `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`.

Answer (score -1):

The Python source documentation does not mention directly that all non-zero integers are evaluate to `True` when passed to an `if` statement, while only zero evaluates to `False`.  You can prove it to yourself with the following code in Python:

```
for test_integer in range(-2, 3, ):
    if not test_integer:
        print('{} evaluates to False in Python.'.format(test_integer))
    else:
        print('{} evaluates to True in Python.'.format(test_integer))
>>>-2 evaluates to True in Python.
-1 evaluates to True in Python.
0 evaluates to False in Python.
1 evaluates to True in Python.
2 evaluates to True in Python.
```

Try it for as far on either side of zero as you want; this code only shows for -2, -1, 0, 1, and 2 inclusive.

Comment: The question is the other way around. The list index being converted from Boolean to  Int but not from String to Int.

Comment: @line-o the question just asked about "what is going on internally," and I attempted to answer that in a way that made sense to me.  I do appreciate the downvote and feedback though.