# How can I count occurrences of elements that are bigger than a given number in an list?

Tags: python, list, count

Let's say I have this list:

```
a = [1.1, 2, 3.1, 4, 5, 6, 7.2, 8.5, 9.1]
```

I want to know how many elements are there bigger than 7. The result should be `3`. Is there an elegant way to do this in Python? I tried with `count` but it won't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1.1 , 2 , 3.1 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7.2 , 8.5 , 9.1]
>>> sum(x > 7 for x in a)
3
```

This uses the fact that `bool`s are `int`s too.

<sub>(If you oppose this because you think it isn't clear or *pythonic* then read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175293/1219006))</sub>

Comment: Didn't know `True` value can be summed.

Comment: @JohnWang Updated my answer, there's nothing special about `True` and `False` btw, they are just `1` and `0`

Answer (score 2):

Even shorter, using numpy:

```
sum(np.array(a)>7)
```

Answer (score 0):

write a function that return you count of elements greater than specific number.

```
def get_max_count(l, num):
    count = 0

    for x in l:
        if x > num:
            count+=1
    return count

l = [1.1, 2, 3.1, 4, 5, 6, 7.2, 8.5, 9.1]
print get_max_count(l=l, num = 7)
```