# how do i find the number of times a word is of len n in python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find the number of times in a list a word is equal to a set length?
So for the example: 'my name is ryan' and 2 the function would give me back 2 as the number of times a word has a length of 2. I have:

```
def LEN(a,b):
'str,int==>int'
'returns the number of words that have a len of b'
c=a.split()
res=0
for i in c:
    if len(i)==b:
        res=res+1
        return(res)
```

But all this gives me is a res of 1 and doesn't go past the first i with a len of c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function works fine, you are just `return`ing early:

```
def LEN(a,b):
        'str,int==>int'
        'returns the number of words that have a len of b'
        c= a.split()
        res = 0
        for i in c:
            if len(i)==b:
                res= res + 1
        return(res) # return at the end
```

This is equivalent to:

```
>>> text = 'my name is ryan'
>>> sum(len(w) == 2 for w in text.split())
2
```

Answer (score 4):

You `return res` inside the for loop, and the program will immediately stop execution once it hits that statement. You can either move it outside the loop, or use this perhaps more pythonic approach:

```
>>> text = 'my name is ryan'
>>> sum(1 for i in text.split() if len(i) == 2)
2
```

Or shorter <strike>but a little less clear</strike> (<strike>but</strike> and [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175293/1907098)):

```
>>> sum(len(i) == 2 for i in text.split())
2
```

The second function is based on that fact that `True == 1`

Comment: I dont know how i didnt see that. Thanks.

Comment: @Volatility You say the second one is less clear, I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3175293/1219006

Comment: @Volatility I was hoping that would convince you it's clear :)

Comment: @Volatility Yes :) Although I'm not sure why your answer was unaccepted

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
>>> s = 'my name is ryan'
>>> map(len, s.split()).count(2)
2
```

Comment: +1 for creativity `;)`. I've never seen this approach before.

Comment: note: to have this work in py3k you have to use `list(map(...)).count`. In Python 3, you could do: `sum(map((2).__eq__, s.split()))` but that's pretty unclear

Comment: @jamylak you mean `sum(map((2).__eq__, map(len, s.split())))`? `;)`