# Counting sublists in a list

Tags: python, list

```
L=[2,4,5,6,2,1,6,6,3,2,4,5,3,4,5]
```

I want to know how many times an arbitrary sub-sequence shows up, `s=[2,4,5]` for instance would return 2 times.

I tried `L.count(s)` but it does not work because I think it is expecting to look for something like `[random numbers ... [2,4,5] ... random numbers]` instead of `2,4,5` without the brackets.

Comment: Necessarily contiguous or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> L = [2,4,5,6,2,1,6,6,3,2,4,5,3,4,5]
>>> s = [2,4,5]
```

```
>>> sum(1 for i in range(len(L)) if L[i:i+len(s)]==s)
2
```

Almost the same thing, slightly shorter (uses the fact that `True` can behave like the number `1`):

```
>>> sum(L[i:i+len(s)]==s for i in range(len(L)))
2
```

Comment: I think it's a bit unreadable, taking advantage of the fact that bool is an int.

Comment: @Elazar No it is **not** a bit unreadable, come back here you have read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3175293/1219006

Comment: @jamylak I did. A year ago, it would have taken me more than a couple of seconds to get that, and I came to Python from C. If I am not the worse programmer in the world (which is possible, I admit) it means it's less readable than using the `if` construct. It's my own personal view, anyway.

Comment: @Elazar Are you saying you read that linked question a year ago? nvm I misread the first part, didn't see the period. Basically it is considered Pythonic to do this, it can be your own personal view if you dislike it...

Comment: @Elazar Don't worry you are not the first, someone always argues that this may be unreadable, but they always know what it means and are just worried for other people, I imagine that's how you are thinking. You needn't worry since this causes people to think about what's going on anyway and they figure it out.

Comment: @jamylak "this causes people to think about what's going on anyway" - when is it not true with unreadable code? I thought our purpose is to make them think less about such details.

Comment: Your string-based one is dangerous: it'll also find `[2, 4, 5]` in `[22, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Important note: This **does** count overlaps. The original question is ambiguous as to what is wanted. In my case this is fine but maybe people reading this will not want this. Example: `L, s = [1,1,1], [1,1]` will return 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=0
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i:i+len(s)]==s:
        x+=1
```

or make it list-comprehension:

```
len([None for i in range(len(L)) if L[i:i+len(s)]==s])
```