# How to Find The Length of a List Containing Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary:

```
>>> Fruits = [{'apple': 'red', 'orange': 'orange'}, {'pear': 'green', 'cherry': 'red', 'lemon': 'yellow'}, {}, {}]
>>> 
>>> len (Fruits)
4

List 0: {'orange': 'orange', 'apple': 'red'}
List 1: {'cherry': 'red', 'lemon': 'yellow', 'pear': 'green'}
List 2: {}
List 3: {}
```

Although len (Fruits) does return the "correct" length, I'm wondering if there's a shortcut command only return the length of the list that has values in them?

Ultimately, I wanted to do:

```
# Length Fruits is expected to be 2 instead of 4.
for i in range (len (Fruits)):
    # Do something with Fruits
    Fruits [i]['grapes'] = 'purple'
```

Comment: Do you want to operate on each dict in Fruits that is non-empty, or are you using i for something interesting? A pythonic solution depends on your intent here. Something like for `i in range( len (Fruits)); Fruits[i]['apple']` is considered an antipattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Count Elements in a List of Objects with Matching Attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455777/python-count-elements-in-a-list-of-objects-with-matching-attributes)

Comment: I'm using "i" as index to add or delete dictionary values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the empty `dict` entries by either:

Use a list comprehension and use the truthiness of the container (it is `True` iff it is non-empty)

```
>>> len([i for i in Fruits if i])
2
```

Use `filter` with `None` to filter against

```
>>> len(list(filter(None, Fruits)))
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either filter the empty dicts and check the len or simply use `sum` add `1` for each non empty dict:

```
Fruits = [{'apple': 'red', 'orange': 'orange'}, {'pear': 'green', 'cherry': 'red', 'lemon': 'yellow'}, {}, {}]

print(sum(1 for d in Fruits if d))
2
```

`if d` will evaluate to `False` for any empty dict so we correctly end up with `2` as the length.

If you want to remove the empty dicts from Fruits:

```
Fruits[:] = (d for d in Fruits if d)

print(len(Fruits))
```

`Fruits[:]` changes the original list, `(d for d in Fruits if d)` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) much like the `sum` example that only keeps the non empty dicts.

Then iterate over the list and access the dicts:

```
for d in Fruits:
   # do something with each dict or Fruits
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `len` here at all, nor `range`:

```
for d in Fruits:
    if not d:
        continue
    # do stuff with non-empty dict d
```

Comment: This would work but I need to iterate over the list.  I would then have to use enumerate.  Thank you for your help though.