# Counting Objects in a List according to a Boolean property

Tags: python, loops, count, sum, boolean

I have a list of objects with a boolean property.

I'd like to count these objects according to this boolean property - None's included.

Are there functions in the standard library that would be more efficient, terser, or more Pythonic than fully writing out a loop to iterate over them?

`Counter` does not seem appropriate, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455777/python-count-elements-in-a-list-of-objects-with-matching-attributes) nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) solve the problem - as far as I can tell.

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, moniker, booleanVariable):
        self.name = moniker
        self.state = booleanVariable

def _myCounterMethod(list):
    # code goes here
    return counts

myList = []
myList.append(MyObject("objectOne", True))
myList.append(MyObject("objectTwo", False))
myList.append(MyObject("objectThree", None))

counts = _MyCounterMethod(myList)
print(counts)
>>>[('True', 1), ('False', 1), ('None', 1)]
```

My current solution:

```
def _myCounterMethod(list):
    trueCount = 0
    falseCount = 0
    noneCount = 0
    for obj in list:
        if obj.state == True:
            trueCount += 1
        elif obj.state == False:
            falseCount += 1
        elif obj.state == None:
            noneCount += 1
    countsList = [('True', trueCount), ('False', falseCount), ('None', noneCount)]
    return countsList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections


class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, moniker, booleanVariable):
        self.name = moniker
        self.state = booleanVariable


my_list = [MyObject("objectOne", True), MyObject("objectTwo", False), MyObject("objectThree", None)]

counts = collections.Counter(str(e.state) for e in my_list)
print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'True': 1, 'False': 1, 'None': 1})
```

If strictly list output is needed do:

```
result = list(counts.items())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('True', 1), ('False', 1), ('None', 1)]
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl It's not a hard requirement, but the end utility _is_ printing state to the console - so it would be convenient.

Answer (score 3):

You are already covered with `Counter` based approaches, here is a simple shortening of what you have:

```
def _myCounterMethod(lst):  # do not shadow `list`
    trueCount = falseCount = noneCount = 0
    for obj in lst:
        trueCount += obj.state is True
        falseCount += obj.state is False
        noneCount += obj.state is None
    return [('True', trueCount), ('False', falseCount), ('None', noneCount)]
```

And for my take on the best approach:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import attrgetter

def _myCounterMethod(lst):
    return Counter(map(attrgetter("state"), lst)).most_common()
    # already a list of tuples
```

Convert whatever you have to strings only when you are printing it really and really need to.

Comment: May or may not be what is desired, but it's already a list and since it is destined for output, descending sort order can only be a plus :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you implement the .count() method

```py
def counter(l):
   iter = [x.state for x in l]
   return ('True', iter.count(True)), ('False', iter.count(False)), ('None', iter.count(None))
```

```py
>>> counter(myList)
(('True', 1), ('False', 1), ('None', 1))
```

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812468/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-python-lists-count-function), count makes use of a loop that iterates over the entire list to find the value of the provided field. So while this is quite readable, you are iterating over the list's length 4 times in total

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(int)
class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, moniker, booleanVariable):
        self.name = moniker
        self.state = booleanVariable
myList = []
myList.append(MyObject("objectOne", True))
myList.append(MyObject("objectTwo", False))
myList.append(MyObject("objectThree", None))
for o in myList:
  data[str(o.state)] += 1
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'True': 1, 'False': 1, 'None': 1})
```