# How do I write a compare function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, doctest

```
def compare(a, b):
    """
    Return 1 if a > b, 0 if a equals b, and -1 if a < b
    >>> compare (5, 7)
    1
    >>> compare (7, 7)
    0
    >>> compare (2, 3)
    -1
    """
```

Comment: your examples are wrong

Comment: If you are writing a compare function in order to pass it to `sort`, this practice is deprecated - write a `key` function instead, it is both *not* deprecated *and* faster.

Comment: Also note that this function already exists as the builtin `cmp`

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> def compare(a, b):
        return (a > b) - (a < b)


>>> compare(5, 7)
-1
>>> compare(7, 7)
0
>>> compare(3, 2)
1
```

A longer, more verbose way would be:

```
def compare(a, b):
    return 1 if a > b else 0 if a == b else -1
```

Which, when flattened out looks like:

```
def compare(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return 1
    elif a == b:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

The first solution is the way to go, remember it [**is** pythonic to treat `bool`s like `int`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints)

Also note that that Python 2 has a `cmp` function which does this:

```
>>> cmp(5, 7)
-1
```

however in Python 3 `cmp` is gone, since the comparisons it is usually used for eg. `list.sort` are now down using a `key` function instead of `cmp`.