# Get the number of times each string occurs in an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function countWords(inputWords) {
var sortArray = inputWords.sort(function (idx1, idx2) { return idx1.localeCompare(idx2) });
var resultArray = [];
var counter = 1;

sortArray.reduce(function (total, currentValue) {
    if (total == currentValue)
        counter++;
    else {
        resultArray.push(counter);
        counter = 1;
    }
    return currentValue;
});

    return resultArray;
}
module.exports = countWords
```

So currently I'm trying to get the number  of times each string occurs in an Array. I wrote the function above, but it seems that it has a bug.

PS: That is an exercise of https://nodeschool.io/ .. npm install -g functional-javascript-workshop . I have to use the reduce function and I'm not allowed to use any for/while loops

That was my input/output:

```
input:      [ 'ad', 'ad', 'ad', 'aliqua', 'aliquip', 'aute', 'consectetur', 'consequat', 'culpa', 'culpa', 'culpa', 'do', 'do', 'dolor', 'dolore', 'eiusmod', 'elit', 'esse', 'esse', 'est', 'et', 'et', 'ex', 'excepteur', 'excepteur', 'exercitation', 'exercitation', 'id', 'id', 'id', 'incididunt', 'labore', 'laborum', 'lorem', 'magna', 'minim', 'minim', 'minim', 'mollit', 'nostrud', 'nulla', 'pariatur', 'proident', 'qui', 'qui', 'reprehenderit', 'reprehenderit', 'sint', 'ullamco', 'velit' ]
submission: [ 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 ]
```

The workshop "says" that this is wrong.

Can somebody help?

Comment: _"The workshop "says" that this is wrong."_ What is "wrong"? Is the result actually incorrect? Have you checked the result?

Comment: start to test on simple inputs without "workshops"

Comment: The workshop check probably has a problem with the order of the results because of the `Array#sort`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding occurrences of a word in a string in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268958/finding-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-python-3)

Comment: @guest271314 the result is wrong, otherwise I would pass the exercise

Comment: @TiZaLjubavNisiRodjena Did you check result? Where is result "wrong"? That is, how will you know when you have the correct answer? How do you know "exercise" is not "wrong"? What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314input:  It prints:
# FAIL

Your solution to Basic: Reduce didn't pass. Try again!

Comment: @guest271314 otherwise it will say pass

Comment: @TiZaLjubavNisiRodjena _"otherwise it will say pass"_ That is not an acceptable answer which would clarify expected result. What is "it"?

Comment: @guest271314 If my result is correct, then cmd prints : # PASS

Your solution to Basic: Reduce passed!

Comment: @TiZaLjubavNisiRodjena That does not answer what is incorrect at `javascript` at Question. Do you know what is "wrong" or incorrect at `javascript` result at Question?

Answer (score 1):

The workshop check probably has a problem with the order of the results you submitted, because of the `Array#sort` you use at the start of the function.

You can use these methods to count without changing the order of the results:

A ES6 word counter with `Array#reduce` that uses [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) syntax and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The `Map` counts the words. The `Map` is converted to an iterator by the `Map#values`, and then to an array using spread.

```js
const words = [ 'ad', 'ad', 'ad', 'aliqua', 'aliquip', 'aute', 'consectetur', 'consequat', 'culpa', 'culpa', 'culpa', 'do', 'do', 'dolor', 'dolore', 'eiusmod', 'elit', 'esse', 'esse', 'est', 'et', 'et', 'ex', 'excepteur', 'excepteur', 'exercitation', 'exercitation', 'id', 'id', 'id', 'incididunt', 'labore', 'laborum', 'lorem', 'magna', 'minim', 'minim', 'minim', 'mollit', 'nostrud', 'nulla', 'pariatur', 'proident', 'qui', 'qui', 'reprehenderit', 'reprehenderit', 'sint', 'ullamco', 'velit' ];

const countWords = (words) => [...words.reduce((m, w) => m.set(w, (m.get(w) || 0) + 1), new Map).values()];

const result = countWords(words);

console.log(result);
```

And the ES5 version that uses `Array#reduce` with a hash object.

```js
var words = [ 'ad', 'ad', 'ad', 'aliqua', 'aliquip', 'aute', 'consectetur', 'consequat', 'culpa', 'culpa', 'culpa', 'do', 'do', 'dolor', 'dolore', 'eiusmod', 'elit', 'esse', 'esse', 'est', 'et', 'et', 'ex', 'excepteur', 'excepteur', 'exercitation', 'exercitation', 'id', 'id', 'id', 'incididunt', 'labore', 'laborum', 'lorem', 'magna', 'minim', 'minim', 'minim', 'mollit', 'nostrud', 'nulla', 'pariatur', 'proident', 'qui', 'qui', 'reprehenderit', 'reprehenderit', 'sint', 'ullamco', 'velit' ];

function countWords(arr) {
  return words.reduce(function(m, w) {
    // if the hash doesn't include the word
    if (!m.hash.hasOwnProperty(w)) {
      // push a new count of 0 to that word
      m.counts.push(0)
      
      // add the index of the word's count
      m.hash[w] = m.counts.length - 1;
    }

    // increment the count at the index of the word's count
    m.counts[m.hash[w]]++;

    return m;
  }, { hash: {}, counts: [] }).counts; // return the counts array
}

var result = countWords(words);

console.log(result);
```