# In "Boys dance, girls dance, he dances, she dances" how to find the number of "dance" only and not "dances" (python)?)"

Tags: python, string-function

In line,

```
Boys dance, girls dance, he dances, she dances
```

how to count the number of times `dance` occurs without counting the number of times `dances` occurs (using a Python program)?

A method is

```
>>> var = "Boys dance, girls dance, he dances, she dances"
>>> count1 = var.count("dance")
>>> count2 = var.count("dances")
>>> count = count1 - count2
>>> count
2
>>>
```

But it is too lengthy.

Is any one line method available?

Comment: Are you allowed to match 'dance,' instead?

Comment: I want to match "dance" but exclude those which are "dances"

Comment: Alternative to the answers and dupe post, you could just not store the counts in variables: `var.count("dance") - var.count("dances")`

Answer (score 3):

This will simply count the number of times the expression "dance" appears

```
import re
print len(re.findall('dance\\b', string))
```

This website should give you more information about the regular expression lib. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 3):

Try below

```
import re
count = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer('(dance[^\\w])', line))
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use Regular Expressions:

```
import re
len(re.findall("dance[^s]", string))
```

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension: Split at `" "`, strip `",."` from splits

```
v = "Boys dance, girls dance, he dances, she dances"
print(len([x for x in v.split() if x.strip(".,") == "dance"]))
```

The answers in [Finding occurrences of a word in a string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268958/finding-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-python-3) using list comprehensions do not deal with punktioations glued to the split words - so decided to answer here as well.