# How to count exact words in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to search a text and count how many times selected words occur. For simplicity, I'll say the text is "Does it fit?" and the words I want to count are "it" and "fit".

I've written the following code:

```
mystring = 'Does it fit?'
search_words = 'it', 'fit'
for sw in search_words:
    frequency = {}
    count = mystring.count(sw.strip())
    output = (sw + ',{}'.format(count))
    print(output)
```

The output is

```
it,2
fit,1
```

because the code counts the 'it' in 'fit' towards the total for 'it'.

The output I want is

```
it,1
fit,1
```

I've tried changing line 5 to `count = mystring.count('\\b'+sw+'\\b'.strip())` but the count is then zero for each word. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding occurrences of a word in a string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268958/finding-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that list syntax is off, heres a way to do it though

```
bad_chars = [';', ':', '!', "*","?","."]
res = {}
for word in ["it","fit"]: 
    res[word] = 0
    string = ''.join((filter(lambda i: i not in bad_chars, "does it fit?")))
    for i in string.split(" "):
        if word == i: res[word] += 1

print(res)
```

by using the `in` keyword you were checking if that string was in another string, in this case `it` was inside `fit`, so you were getting 2 occurrences of `it`

here it directly compares the words after removing punctuation/special characters!

output:

```
{'it': 1, 'fit': 1}
```

Comment: That gives me the same answer: {'it': 2, 'fit': 1}.

Comment: oh sorry i misread, thats an easy fix! let me edit it

Comment: Thanks, but `bad_chars` is not defined. How should I define it?

Comment: sorry i entered it in wrong: ```bad_chars = [';', ':', '!', "*","?","."], thanks for catching that, should be visible now

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the regex pattern that you have tried implementing in your original post is with `str.count()` rather than the pattern itself.

`str.count()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)) returns the count of non-overlapping occurrences of the `str` passed as a parameter within the `str` that the method is applied to - so `'lots of love'.('lo')` will return `2` - however, `str.count()` is for substring identification using string literals **only** and will not work with regular expression patterns.

The below solution using your original pattern and the built in `re` module should work nicely for you.

```py
import re

mystring = 'Does it fit?'
search_words = 'it', 'fit'

results = dict()

for sw in search_words:
    count = re.findall(rf'\b{sw}\b', mystring)
    results[sw] = 0 if not count else len(count)

for k, v in results.items():
    print(f'{k}, {v}')
```

If you want to get matches from `search_words` regardless of their case - e.g for each occurrence of the substrings `'Fit'`, `'FIT'`, `'fIt'` etc. present in `mystring` to be included in the count stored in `results['fit']`  - you can achieve this by changing the line:

```py
    count = re.findall(rf'\b{sw}\b', mystring)
```

to

```py
    count = re.findall(rf'\b{sw}\b', mystring, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me an error message:     `for k, v in results:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @Belmonte Whoops, sorry about that. Fixed in update to my answer. Penultimate line should be `for k, v in results.items():`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def count_words(string, *args):
    words = string.split()
    search_words = args
    frequency_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i][-1] == '?':
            words[i] = words[i][:-1]
    for word in search_words:
        frequency_dict[word] = words.count(word)
    for word, count in frequency_dict.items():
        print(f'{word}, {count}')
```

You can do,

```
count_words('Does it it it fit fit it?', 'it', 'fit')
```

And the output is,

```
it, 4
fit, 2
```