# Recursive Function Inside of a Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that writes how many occurrences of several strings in one single text there are. The reason why I'm using recursion here is because I'm trying to solve a more complex problem this way, where it feels like a simple loop would not be as efficient or would look messy.

So we have a string cat = 'cat kat not kat cat kat c not c' and a list of strings we need to look for: search = ['cat', 'kat']. I'm trying to return a list that gives the number of occurrences of each word: result = [2, 3].
Here's my code:

```
cat = 'cat kat not kat cat kat c not c'
search = ['cat', 'kat']
result = []

def cat_main(cat, search, result):
    for el in search:
        count1 = cat.count(el)
        return look_for_cat(el, search, count1, result)

def look_for_cat(el, search, count1, result):
    if count1 == 0:
        return result
    else:
        result.append(el)
        count1 -= 1
        look_for_cat(el, search, count1, result)
```

When I call the cat_main function, it doesn't return anything. When I try to print things inside of both functions separately, it seems to work, so I'm probably making some dumb mistake but I have no idea why it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to debug your code and step through it is [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=cat%20%3D%20%27cat%20kat%20not%20kat%20cat%20kat%20c%20not%20c%27%0Asearch%20%3D%20%5B%27cat%27,%20%27kat%27%5D%0Aresult%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0Adef%20cat_main%28cat,%20search,%20result%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20el%20in%20search%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count1%20%3D%20cat.count%28el%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20look_for_cat%28el,%20search,%20count1,%20result%29%0A%0Adef%20look_for_cat%28el,%20search,%20count1,%20result%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20count1%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.append%28el%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count1%20-%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20look_for_cat%28el,%20search,%20count1,%20result%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Acat_main%28cat,%20search,%20result%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

But I would solve your problem with a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) like so:

```
>>> [cat.split().count(word) for word in search]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Note that in its current form, if you added `'c'` to `search` then it would return a result of 4 (as there are 4 instances of the character 'c' within the `cat` string).

Comment: @NeilStudd Good catch. I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest BioGeek solution, however, if you wanted to fix yours here it is...

```
cat = 'cat kat not kat cat kat c not c'
search = ['cat', 'kat']
result = []

def cat_main(cat, search, result):
    result_list = []
    for el in search:
        count1 = cat.count(el)
        temp_result = look_for_cat(el, search, count1, result)
        result_list.append(temp_result)
    return result_list

def look_for_cat(el, search, count1, result):
    if count1 != 0:
        result.append(el)
        count1 -= 1
        look_for_cat(el, search, count1, result)
    return result

print(cat_main(cat, search, result))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it readable, then you can achieve this without recursion in the following manner:

```
cat = 'cat kat not kat cat kat c not c'
search = ['cat', 'kat']
result = []

for word in search:
     result.append(cat.split().count(word))

print(result) # [2, 3]
```

The `split()` ensures it tokenizes `cat` into individual words, so that a search for `c` would return 2 rather than 4.

If efficiency is more important for you, refer to the marked answer of this question: [Finding occurrences of a word in a string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268958/finding-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

This should work(if you want only through reccursion)

```
cat = 'cat kat not kat cat kat c not c'
search = ['cat', 'kat']
result = []


def cat_main():
    for el in search:
        count1 = cat.count(el)
        print(count1)
        look_for_cat(el, count1) #if you return here it will exist out of function 
                                 #doesnt continue for further elements in search list


def look_for_cat(el, count1):
    if count1 == 0:
        return
    else:
        result.append(count1) #no need to append words according to your question, just their count

cat_main()
print(result)
```