# Find the occurrence of a particular word from a file in python

Tags: python, count, txt

I have a text file which contains some lines as follows
input text

```
 guildenstern32_7
    Nay, good my lord, this courtesy is **not** of the right breed.
    If it shall please you to make me a wholesome answer, I will do
    your mother's commandment: if **not**, your pardon and my return
    shall be the end of my business.
    
    guildenstern32_8
    What, my lord?
    
    guildenstern32_9
    O my lord, if my duty be too bold, my love is too unmannerly.
    
    guildenstern32_10
    My lord, I cannot.
    
    guildenstern32_11
    Believe me, I cannot.
```

the code is as follows

```
   file = open("file.txt", "r")
    
    #read content of file to string
    data = file.read()
    
    
    #get number of occurrences of the substring in the string
    occurrences = data.count('not') 
    
    print('Number of occurrences of the word :', occurrences)
    file.close()
```

the output yields the occurrences as 4 but it has only to not's. It also considers cannot also. how to avoid that??

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268958/finding-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-python-3

Comment: I think you need a regular expression