# Count all that satisfy a condition in Python

Tags: python, loops

Is there a way to add all that satisfy a condition in a shorthand nested loop? My following attempt was unsuccessful:

```
count += 1 if n == fresh for n in buckets['actual'][e] else 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
sum(n == fresh for n in buckets['actual'][e])
```

as `True == 1`  and `False == 0`, so `else` is not required.

---

Related reads: [Is it Pythonic to use bools as ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints) 
, [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable implicitly using the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`, you can make this fact explicit by doing `int(n == fresh)`.  This is only useful to make the code more obvious... the language doesn't care.

Comment: Sure, but there is also the line [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  I personally don't care, but it was in case the OP has a gut reaction against implicitly using `bool`s as `int`s.  To be clear, I'm not saying you are wrong... my comment was an addendum intended for the OP in case they wanted to make a more self-documenting code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sum()` function:

```
sum(1 if n == fresh else 0  for n in buckets['actual'][e])
```

or:

```
sum(1 for n in buckets['actual'][e] if n == fresh)
```