# Clarification about a list method

Tags: python, list, function, methods

From Python docs:

**list.index(x):
Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.**

But, the following examples return these in the Python shell:

```
>>> [1, 2,True, 3, 'a', 4].index(True)
0
>>> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4].index(True)
0
```

As you can see, it seems to be returning 0 even when True is not present in the list. This seems to be happening only when the parameter is True in list.index():

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because :

```
>>> True == 1
True
```

`list.index` performs equality check, so, it returns the index `0` for you.

```
>>> lis = [1, 2,True, 3, 'a', 4]
>>> next(i for i, x in enumerate(lis) if x == True)
0
>>> lis = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4]
>>> next(i for i, x in enumerate(lis) if x == True)
0
```

---

**Related:**

[Is it Pythonic to use bools as ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints)

[Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Comment: Thank you, that clarified it for me. Though, yhy does True == 1 return True? I mean, it makes no sense because 1 and True are definitely not the same, do you know why they are apparently the same?

Comment: `True` and `1` are *exactly* the same. `True` is just `1` wearing a fancy suit.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `True == 1`:

```
>>> True == 1
True
```

So the result is in accordance with the documentation, i.e. the index of the first element that `== True` is returned. In this case, that's `1` at index `0`.