# Priority of operators: > and ==

Tags: python, boolean, operators, operator-precedence

I'm trying to guess which operator has priority: `>` (greater than) or `==` (equal). This is my experiment:

```
>>> 5 > 4 == 1
False
```

As far as I know, this has two possible solutions.

```
>>> (5 > 4) == 1
True
>>> 5 > (4 == 1)
True
```

Neither one returns `False`, so how is the first code resolved by Python?

Comment: You could look this up, but +1 for questioning a (perhaps) counterintuitive result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has to do with operator chaining.  Unlike C/C++ and most other languages, Python allows you to chain comparison operators just like you would in normal mathematics. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is
>   equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once
>   (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be
>   false).

So, this expression:

```
5 > 4 == 1
```

is actually interpreted as:

```
5 > 4 and 4 == 1  # Except that 4 is only evaluated once.
```

which becomes:

```
True and False
```

which is `False`.

---

Using parenthesis however changes how Python interprets your comparison.  This:

```
(5 > 4) == 1
```

becomes:

```
True == 1
```

which is `True` (see below for why).  Same goes for:

```
5 > (4 == 1)
```

which becomes:

```
5 > False
```

which is also `True`.

---

Because of [PEP 0285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/), `bool` was made a subclass of `int` and `True == 1` while `False == 0`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>>
```

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation, just for reference: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: @iCodez the interpretation with chaining is 5 > 4 and 4 == 1

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot.

Comment: "historical reasons" makes it seem like an unintended quirk of backwards compatibility; it's actually [working by design](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6865824/1763356).

Comment: @Veedrac - I always assumed that it was made that way to keep in line with C/C++ bools (yes, I know C didn't have a bool type for awhile, but many people would do something like `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` to achieve the same result).  I'll change the wording though since it is really just a way to include the PEP link. :)