# Can anyone explain how this works [1,2][bool("")]?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have no idea how this code works and it returns an output of the first element in the list.

I have tried with different inputs since though I'm getting all the same output.

```
[1,2,3][bool("")]
```

Comment: `""` is falsy in Python; so `bool("")` evaluates to `False`. `False` when used as an integer is `0` (`True` being `1`); `aList[0]` will return the first element.

Comment: i get it thanks to you both.

Comment: Related: [Is it Pythonic to use bools as ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3174392/1639625)

Answer (score 0):

Since `bool("")==False`. Also, `False` is 0. Therefore `[1,2,3][bool("")]` is same as `[1,2,3][0]` which return first element of list ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool("")==0
```

This is because `""` is regarded as `false`. This means your statement will be,

```
[1,2,3][0]
```

which returns the first element of the list. In this case

```
1
```

Source: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool