# Equivalent of 'ismember' from Matlab in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to perform a comparison between the rows of two matrices A and B with the same number of columns.

In matlab the command `ismember(a, b, 'rows')` returns a vector containing 1 where the rows of A are also rows of B and 0 otherwise, and also returns the highest index in B for each element in A that is a member of B.

```
[tf, index] = ismember(A, B, 'rows');
```

Is there an equivalent function in python? Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

you can get your vector as

```
same_rows = [a == b for a,b in zip(A, B)]
```

Note that this will yield `True` and `False` instead of 1 and 0 but `bool` is subclassed from `int` and `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

to get the max row where this occurs, you can just use

```
max_row = next(i for i, row in enumerate(reversed(same_rows)) if row == True)
```

If you want the number of rows that they have in common, you can just use

```
same_count == sum(same_rows)
```

Note that this is all for python and assumes that matrices are lists of lists or tuples or tuples of lists or tuples. HTH.

Comment: or you could just use `map( eq, A, B)` using `eq` from `operator`, also note in Python 3.x that bool is no longer an int but it's own type.

Comment: @wheaties: bool is still an int, in Python 3.  In fact, `issubclass(bool, int)` returns True.  You can have a look at the full discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-guaranteed-by-t

Comment: Note that same_rows = [a == b for a,b in zip(A, B)], gives me yield only True where the rows are equal only at corresponding rows (e.g a[0,:] = b[0,:]) but i need to find all the positions where a row of a is in b.

Answer (score 1):

The `ismember` library can be helpful.

```
pip install ismember
```

Example:

```
# Import library
from ismember import ismember

# Example with random matrices
a_vec = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,8))
b_vec = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,10))

# Row-wise comparison
Iloc, idx = ismember(a_vec, b_vec, 'rows')

# These should all be True
for i in np.arange(0,a_vec.shape[0]):
    np.all(a_vec[i,Iloc[i]]==b_vec[i,idx[i]])
```