# Unbelievable python boolean feature

Tags: python, boolean, python-2.6

```
>>> a = False
>>> b = False
>>> a | b
True
>>> a
True
>>> b
True
```

I get this in a python interpreter.

I just don't think so. Is there any detailed material about python `boolean type`?

I use *Python 2.6.6*, thanks!

Comment: are you sure this is it?  what platform?

Comment: I am sure, something is wrong with your interpreter. please Exit and try again. http://uthcode.codepad.org/DLc4pEPQ

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 here too, but the results I get are the expected ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see only one context in which your problem makes sense:

```
>>> False = True
>>> a = False
>>> b = False
>>> a | b
True
>>> a
True
>>> b
True
>>>
```

To start debugging - what's the result of `print int(False)`? If the above happened, you should get `1`. Try:

```
>>> False = bool(0)
>>> a = False
>>> b = False
>>> a | b
False
```

As far as why this happened - maybe someone played a prank on you and changed the value of `False` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarantee/2764161#2764161))? I really can't think of anything else that would cause this. You could always set `False` to `bool(0)` in modules where you need it, to guard against this.

Or switch to Python 3, which makes `True` and `False` reserved words which can't be changed.

Answer (score 4):

Something is wrong with your interpreter:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> False | False
False
>>> a = False
>>> b = False
>>> a | b
False
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` is the [bitwise-or](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html) operator in python.

If you're doing a conditional check you should use the `or` operator:

```
>>> a = False
>>> b = False
>>> a or b
False
>>> a
False
>>> b
False
```

You can read more about bitwise operators [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Edit/Side Note: After running the code you posted in your question, I am not getting the same results... there may be something wrong with your installation...

Comment: Thanks for you link! I just can't believe what i got from my interpreter :-)