# Why does 1 == True but 2 != True in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarantee)

A brief transcript from my interactive console:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 29 2011, 11:10:00) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True
True
>>> 0 == True
False
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 2 == True
False
```

Why on earth is this the case?

**Edit:** For the sake of contrast, consider the `is` operator.

```
>>> 0 is False
False
>>> 1 is True
False
>>> 0 is 0
True
>>> True is True
True
```

That makes a lot of sense because though `1` and `True` both mean the same thing as the condition of an `if` statement, they really aren't the same thing.

**Edit again:** More fun consequences of `1 == True`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[True] = "hello"
>>> d[1]
"hello"
```

Comment: See definition of true http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans

Comment: The question should be why `2 != True`

Comment: Is there a reference manual of sorts on docs.python.org?

Comment: Convention. In Visual Basic, the identities are `True=-1` and `False=0`. If you test `True=+2` or `True=1` or `False=0.4575` or `False=-999` in VB, they will all return false. In Python: same idea, different specifics. Nothing mysterious about `2 != True`.

Comment: __There is no why__, (Sorry, I can't help it.)

Comment: @Clueless would you mind if the question is edited to "Why does 1==True but 2!=True in Python"?

Comment: Well, the part about `d[1] is d[True]` is unexpected...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because Boolean in Python is a subtype of integers. From the documentation:

> Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True. They are used to represent truth values (although other values can also be considered false or true). In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively. The built-in function bool() can be used to cast any value to a Boolean, if the value can be interpreted as a truth value (see section Truth Value Testing above).

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values

Comment: Yeah, this explains *how*, but it seems like a strange decision. It means `==` has very strange behavior. I like the behavior of the `is` operator way better, where booleans and integers are never equal to each other.

Comment: @Clueless: Be careful with `is`, becuase *integers* are sometimes not equal to each other, either: [Python "is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: +1 for quoting the documentation. The section on Truth Value Testing is also very important to read.

Comment: @Greg Well, that's depressing. So I have to use `==` and I can't rely on it separating types cleanly...

Comment: @Clueless The designer of Python _chose_ to allow values of one type to behave as values of another type seemingly more frequently than not.  Python is not like Java where booleans and integers are not implicitly interchangeable.  That said, when "separation" is desired, you can use [Python's built-in `type` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type).

Comment: @Ray Toal There was actually quite some discussion about exactly this topic when bools were implemented. I think the final reason they went with the current implementation was backwards compatibility (though I fear the day when I find a program that uses integer arithmetic on booleans)

Comment: @Voo It's occasionally helpful when doing code golf. `("thing 1","thing 2")[x==0]`. I'm not sure "helpful for code golf" is a good thing for any language feature though.

Answer (score 28):

Because instances of `bool` are also instances of `int` in python. `True` happens to be equals to integer `1`.

Take a look at this example:

```
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry to rain on a good answer but `<pedantic>` There is no type `boolean` -- it's `bool`, and `isinstance(bool, int) == False`, so I think you meant to say "Instances of `bool` are also instances of `int`" or "Boolean values are instances of `int`". `</pedantic>` Cheers.

Comment: @Ray Toal: Thanks for pointing that out. Very helpful. Corrected the answer to reflect what you have just mentioned.

Comment: Great, now here's an upvote for a Nice Answer badge.  Good use of `isinstance` by the way.  Gets to the point of why `2 != True` nicely.

Answer (score 13):

It's standard binary conventions: 1 is true, 0 is false.

It's like 1 means "on" in machine language, and 0 means "off".

Because of this the `bool` type is just a subtype of `int` in Python, with `1 == True` and `0 == False`.

However any non-zero numeric value will be evaluated as `True` in a conditional statement:

```
>>> if 2: print "ok"
ok
>>> 2 == True
False
```

Comment: Actually there's at least one language where true is defined as -1 (and actually Win32 uses that definition rarely as well). Has lead to some quite interesting bugs I hear.

Comment: To explain my answer, the original question did not mention that `2 != True`, it was just "Why does `1 == True` in python?" It was edited later

Answer (score 12):

Once upon a time (in Python < 2.3), there was no boolean type, no `False` or `True`, only `0` and `1`. Then [PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) came along and thus they were added to the language. They were defined so that `True == 1` and `False == 0`, probably for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Equality testing is different than boolean testing:

```
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(2)
True
>>> bool(-1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

Comment: It just seems to me like `==` should either recognize all values that are "true" as interpreted by python or it should be strict. It's not loosey-goosey because `2 == True` evaluates to false, and it's not strict because `1 == True` evaluates to true even though they are totally different types. So it's inconsistent.

Comment: @Clueless But if you allowed that, you could "prove" `1==2` since you'd expect the equality operation to be transitive (and therefore `1 == True == 2`). Now that's quite inconsistent as well and much more problematic imo ;)

Comment: It's not actually *that* far out. It's just an equivalence class on non-zero integers. But I agree, we don't want `1 == 2` to be true in general because it would make for a pretty useless operator. Much better would be just make `1 == True` be false, seeing as they are totally different things mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

It's a boolean thing.  1 == true, 0 == false.

Answer (score 0):

because in binary 1 is true and 0 is false.
it also happens in PHP.

I'm not sure about other languages, but I think it's going to be the same.

Comment: So "is" in Python === "===" in PHP?

Comment: @Mark: (disclaimer: I don't know a huge amount about Python) but from what I've read here it seems that `is` is more like a reference check, which is why `2 is 2` can be false.

Answer (score -1):

It's binary. 0 is always False and 1 is always True. In python though any non-zero value, including negative values are always True.

```
>>> if -1:
...     print 'a'
...
a
>>> if 2:
...     print 'a'
...
a
>>> if 0:
...     print 'a'
...
>>>
```

Comment: -1 `In python though any non-zero value, including negative values are always True.` -- he just pasted a snippet that demonstrates that this is not the case.

Comment: As Bill Clinton might say, it depends what the meaning of "are" is. `2 is True` is false (as is `1 is True`). Sure, `bool()` will return `True` for non-zero integer inputs, but that doesn't mean the values "are" `True`.

Comment: The snippet proves that 2 is not a binary number. It doesn't prove that python evaluates non-zero numbers, lists etc as true.

Comment: This answer kind of sidesteps the question.  The OP wanted to know why `1 == True` but `2 != True`.  Equality is different from "evaluation in a boolean context."