# Is it guaranteed that False "is 0" and True "is 1"?

Tags: python, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

I noticed today that the following works using python 2.6 (Cpython)...

```
>>> a=[100,200]
>>> a[True]
200
>>> a[False]
100
```

Is this portable to other python implementations (e.g. is `True`/`False` guaranteed to inherit from int?  Is `True` guaranteed to evaluate to 1 instead of some other non-zero number?)  Is there any situation where this would be useful?  It seems like it could be used as another form of a ternary operator, but I don't know how much is gained there...

Comment: (Not an answer, but you may find it interesting: In Python 2.6 and before True and False are just variables so ... `True, False = "hello", "world"` ... but they have proper *reserved* status in Python 3.x)

Comment: As far as I know, True and False are labels for 1 and 0. 1==True and 0==False. Therefore, it would return the 0th and 1st items in the list

Comment: @gwynhowell: no, `True` and `False` are objects in their own right, of type `bool`.

Comment: @gwynhowell  Yes, that is what I show (as far as returning the 0 and 1 item in the list), but I wonder if it is guaranteed by the standard, or an implementation detail...  Also note that True and False are not exactly the same as 1 and 0  (`True is 1` -> `False`, `False is 0` -> `False`)

Comment: @larsmans  Yes, this is a duplicate of that question.  I didn't find that in my searching.  Thanks.

Comment: In 2.6 and 2.7, they are `int`s. I sometimes used to use them to pick the correct execution. Eg: eval(["y/x", "x/y"][x>y]). But using a ternary operator is better in almost all cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [part of the language specification](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), so any Python implementation *should* implement the booleans as equivalent to the integers.

> Booleans
>
> > These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of plain integers, and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings `"False"` or `"True"` are returned, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Yes -- this is guaranteed -- with the caveat that `True` and `False` may be reassigned; but that doesn't affect the results of boolean operations. (Thanks to [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10263976/577088) for the documentary proof.) In fact, back when there was no ternary operator, this was one of the methods used to emulate it. Nowadays, if you want a ternary operator, use the ternary operator. But sometimes this construct is still useful. For example:

```
>>> even_odd = [[], []]
>>> for i in range(10):
...     even_odd[i % 2 == 1].append(i)
... 
>>> print even_odd
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

You can do this with a dictionary as well. It has a ternary operator equivalent...

```
>>> even, odd = [], []
>>> for i in range(10):
...     (even if i % 2 == 1 else odd).append(i)
... 
>>> even, odd
([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

But I actually find the list-indexing version easier to read, at least in this case. YYMV.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just say `even_odd[i % 2].append(i)`?