# Subtract boolean from float in python

Tags: python

Anyways when debuging my code I found statement that basically subtracted `boolean` from `float`.

Then I tried following in python console:

```
>>> 15.0 - True 
14.0
>>> 15.0 - False
15.0
```

Can anyone explain to me:

- Why subtracting booleans from numeric types is legal (the docs only state that you can do `and`, `not` and `or` on boolean values: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)
- Has this any practical use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values

  > Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True. They are used to represent truth values (although other values can also be considered false or true).
  >
  > In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively.
- not really nowadays, but you can write

  `result = numeric_value * a_bool` *(this one is used a lot, for example, in shader languages)*

  instead of

  `result = numeric_value if a_bool else 0`

  or

  `result = (value_if_false, value_if_true)[a_bool]`

  Don't do any of that though.

It's mostly what people with experience in lower-level languages expect, why take that away from them? In C, true and false are still macros for 1 and 0.

Before 2.3, there was no `bool` type in Python as well, so when it was introduced making it a subclass of `int` made sure no code was broken.

Comment: I have done `result = (value_if_false, value_if_true)[a_bool]` when it is faster.  great answer tho +1

Comment: @Noelkd: faster than a ternary `if`?

Comment: In some toy code when we where doing speed comps in the office yes, will have to wait till tomorrow for examples. ( edit: maybe not ternary if)

Comment: A similar answer to complement this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/25450 (Strictly speaking, in Python2 `True` and `False` can be reassigned: `True, False = 2, 0; 15.0 - True` => `13.0`)

Comment: disassembling a ternary operator call and @Noelkd 's expression: ternary operator performs 4 more calls when looking at bytecode mnemonics vs. 4 overall in the tuple-expression.

Comment: @PavelAnossov it looks like it truely is faster.

Comment: @benjamin I'd say it depends: http://pastebin.com/4XabHEBf

Comment: :) that's what logic dictates: If there is a language construct, it should be optimized. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @benjamin: ternary `if` will also be much faster if it's expensive to evaluate `expression_is_false`, but `a_bool` turns out to be True.

Comment: @PavelAnossov, I played a bit further around with timeit and sometimes tuple-notation would outperform ternary (n=30*10^6, 100*10⁶, multiple runs). I am not going to compare this in depth, but rather stay with the ternary.

Comment: @PavelAnossov, http://pastebin.com/cA69xe0j, builds the tuple imho more efficient. But the ternary is still faster ~6.5% using timeit from the command-line with e.g.: python -m timeit -r 20 -v -n 5000000 "import speedcomp; speedcomp.array_access(False)".

Answer (score 6):

It is legal, because `bool` is a subclass of `int`:

```py
>>> bool.__bases__
(<type 'int'>,)
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

Yes, it has some practical application. For example it was possible to do something like that before ternary statement was introduced:

```py
result = [value_if_false, value_if_true][condition]
```

Which basically does what would be done in this code:

```py
if condition:
    result = value_if_false
else:
    result = value_if_true
```

Other practical usages are:

- you can `sum` several checks / booleans to receive number of results equaling `True`,
- you can multiply by the result of the check:

  ```py
  result = can_count_a * a + can_count_b * b
  ```

Comment: What is the formal name for this? It's very similar to the ability to add a float to an int and have a float returned.

Comment: @MikeVella: Formal name of what? Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, when you are adding `bool` to `float`, the result is almost identical to adding `int` to `float`. Are you asking about _coercion_?

Comment: yes! *coercion* is just the term I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

True evaluates to 1 and False evaluates to 0.

```
>>> True is 1
False
>>> True == 1
True
>>>
```

Bool is a subclass of int. As stated in [PEP-285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/):

> 6) Should bool inherit from int?
>
> => Yes.
>
> In an ideal world, bool might be better implemented as a separate
>   integer type that knows how to perform mixed-mode arithmetic. 
>   However, inheriting bool from int eases the implementation enormously
>   (in part since all C code that calls PyInt_Check() will continue to
>   work -- this returns true for subclasses of int).  Also, I believe
>   this is right in terms of substitutability: code that requires an int
>   can be fed a bool and it will behave the same as 0 or 1.  Code that
>   requires a bool may not work when it is given an int; for example, 3 &
>   4 is 0, but both 3 and 4 are true when considered as truth values.

This isn't of any much practical use and there are other answers with `sudo` examples of using bools. I thought it would be good to have some *real* examples:

```
f,b="Fizz","Buzz"
print "\n".join([["",f,b,f+b][(x%3==0) + 2*(x%5==0)] or str(x) for x in range(1,101)])
```

The section in question:

```
["",f,b,f+b][(x%3==0) + 2*(x%5==0)]
```

The selection of the return each line is based on two boolean expressions, if both are true we get `(True) + 2*(True)` which evaluates to 4 which is a fizzbuzz. Not too hard to understand once you get used to the idea that `True == 1` and `False == 0`

Further more keeping with the theme:

```
print '\n'.join(['Fizz'*(not i%3) + 'Buzz'*(not i%5) or str(i) for i in range(1, 101)])
```

This example relies on what happens when you multiply strings in python:

```
>>> "Noelkd" * False
''
```

And that not True evaluates to 0:

```
>>> not True == 0
True
```

Uses for this fall into two categories:

- Making harder to read code.
- Competing in code golf competitions.