# Dictionary coercion intentional or no?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I write:

```
d = { 0:'a', 1:'b' }
d[False] = 'c'
d[True] = 'd'
print(d)
```

I get:

```
{ 0:'c', 1:'d' }
```

Why is it coercing them into ints? It does the same thing in reverse.

```
d = {False:'a', True:'b'}
d[0] = 'c'
d[1] = 'd'
print(d)
```

Output is:

```
{False:'c', True: 'd'}
```

Can this be disabled? Is it a bug?

Comment: Notice that `isinstance(True, int)` returns `True`. If I recall correctly, booleans are just special subclasses of `int`.

Comment: Yep, `True.__class__.__base__` is `<type 'int'>`.

Comment: Related: [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhari: for the definition of True and False see here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans

Comment: @Humbalan I think I pretty much know what they mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because those values are considered equal:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> 
>>> False == 0
True
```

and have the same hash values:

```
>>> hash(True), hash(1)
(1, 1)
>>> 
>>> hash(False), hash(0)
(0, 0)
```

Therefore, from the dictionary's point of view, `True` and `1` are indistinguishable as are `False` and `0`.

There is no way to "disable" this -- you shouldn't be using non-homogenous keys in a dict to begin with.

A potential workaround in this specific case would be to reserve special int values for `True` and `False` other than `1` and `0`, respectively (presuming you need `1` and `0` as independent keys). For instance, you could have `-1` represent `True` and `-2` represent `False`.

Answer (score 6):

Just offering some background on arshajii's answer.

The two boolean values, `True` and `False`, have a strange relation with integers.

On one hand, they have different string representations, and have separate identities:

```
>>> print(True)
True
>>> print(1)
1

>>> True is 1
False
```

On the other hand, they behave as integers under comparisons and arithmetic:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True + 1
2
```

The reason for this behavior is compatibility. A long time ago, the `bool` type didn't exist. "Boolean" operators copied C behavior, reusing `0` and `1` for "false" and "true".

Eventually Guido realized [this didn't make much sense](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/), and added the constants we know and love.

But there was a problem. Even then, there was already a lot of code that treated boolean values like integers. If boolean operations started using the "correct" type, all this code would break.

So Guido made a compromise. Booleans have their own type, `bool`, and display differently to integers. But in arithmetic operations and comparisons, most notably `__eq__` and `__hash__`, they are treated as one and the same. So old code would continue to work, while new code can still take advantage of the new `bool` type.

Maybe that'll change in Python 4. But for now, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and we'll have to live with that.

(On a related note, that's one of the reasons why `True` and `False` are in Title Case, rather than lower case like other Python keywords.)

Comment: They aren't aliases...if they were, `False is 0` would be `True`. I understand what you mean, but just for clarity...

Comment: Edited and fixed. That's what happens when you StackOverflow right before leaving for work ;)

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is a subclass of `int` whose *representation* is "False" or "True", but whose *value* is 0 or 1.

Comment: there's more than just the value -- It also has the same hashing function.