# Why is this lambda involving a list.index() call so slow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, cprofile

Using cProfile:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   17.834   17.834 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.007    0.007   17.834   17.834 basher.py:5551(_refresh)
        1    0.000    0.000   10.522   10.522 basher.py:1826(RefreshUI)
        4    0.024    0.006   10.517    2.629 basher.py:961(PopulateItems)
      211    1.494    0.007    7.488    0.035 basher.py:1849(PopulateItem)
      231    0.074    0.000    6.734    0.029 {method 'sort' of 'list' objects}
      215    0.002    0.000    6.688    0.031 bosh.py:4764(getOrdered)
     1910    3.039    0.002    6.648    0.003 bosh.py:4770(<lambda>)
      253    0.178    0.001    5.600    0.022 bosh.py:3325(getStatus)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.508    5.508 bosh.py:4327(refresh)
     1911    3.051    0.002    3.330    0.002 {method 'index' of 'list' objects}
```

The `1910    3.039    0.002    6.648    0.003 bosh.py:4770(<lambda>)` line puzzles me. At bosh.py:4770 I have `modNames.sort(key=lambda a: (a in data) and data.index(a))`, data and modNames being lists. Notice `1911    3.051    0.002    3.330    0.002 {method 'index' of 'list' objects}` which seems to come from this line.

So why is this so slow ? Any way I can rewrite this `sort()` so it performs faster ?

EDIT: a final ingredient I was missing to grok this lambda:

```
>>> True and 3
3
```

Comment: The function body is `a in data and data.index(a)` and the two operations in it are O(n) where n is the list size of data. Without answering your entire question, I would place the blame on this lambda function. Each time it is called, the lambda will scan through `data`. If you use a dict for `data` instead of a list, it'll probably be faster since dict has an average lookup time complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As YardGlassOfCode stated, it's not the `lambda` per se which is slow, it is the O(n) operation inside the lambda which is slow. Both `a in data` and `data.index(a)` are [`O(n)` operations](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), where `n` is the length of `data`. And as an additional affront to efficiency, the call to `index` repeats much of the work done in `a in data` too. If the items in `data` are hashable, then you can speed this up considerably by first preparing a dict:

```
weight = dict(zip(data, range(len(data))))
modNames.sort(key=weight.get)  # Python2, or
modNames.sort(key=lambda a: weight.get(a, -1))  # works in Python3
```

This is much quicker because [each dict lookup is a `O(1)` operation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Note that `modNames.sort(key=weight.get)` relies on None comparing as less than integers:

```
In [39]: None < 0
Out[39]: True
```

In Python3, `None < 0` raises an `TypeError`. So `lambda a: weight.get(a, -1)` is used to return -1 when `a` is not in `weight`.

Comment: Thanks - will test it and post back. So I guess also that the original worked because `False < 0` also (sort(key=...) could use some docs)

Comment: [Since `False == 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017/190597), `False < 0` is False, and `0 < False` is False. That means in the original, the 0 indexed item could get sandwiched in between items not in `data`. Consider, for example, `sorted([False, 0, False])`.

Comment: NB: I used `key=lambda a: dataDict.get(a, sys.maxint)` as I wanted items that are absent to be ordered to the bottom python 2.7.8