# Do not understand why if condition evaluates to True when variable is integer

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, int, boolean

I am working with code that exhibits the following behavior. Suppose I have a variable `d` and I assign it to an integer `9`

```
d = 9
```

why do the following statements work?

```
In [95]: if d:
   ....:     print d
   ....: else:
   ....:     print 'Did not print d!'
   ....:     
9

In [96]:
```

when d itself is not a Boolean and does not pass the following tests:

```
In [96]: d is True
Out[96]: False

In [97]: d is False
Out[97]: False
```

I will appreciate it if someone could explain this to me and point out any misconception that I have. Thank you very much.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, `is` tests for identity. Your `d is True` and `d is False` statements are returning False because `d` is `9`, not `True` or `False`. However, the truthy value of `d` is True - try running `bool(d)` to get its Boolean value (hint: it'll return `True`).

As stated elsewhere, False, None, 0, and empty strings, lists, dicts, sets, tuples, etc. are all considered falsy. Objects can also be falsy depending on the contents of their `__nonzero__` and/or `__len__` attributes, if set.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans),

> **In the context of Boolean operations**, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). **All other values are interpreted as true.**

The `if` statement falls under the *context of Booelan operations*. Since `d` being `9` doesn't fall under any of the false values, it is considered as Truthy.

You can confirm the same like this

```
>>> all(bool(value) is False for value in (False, 0, +0, -0, "", (), [], {}, set()))
True
```

Though the value `9` is neither `True` nor `False`, which you determined with `d is True` and `d is False` tests, it is considered as Truthy because of the above mentioned reason.

```
>>> bool(9)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the integer is treated as a **boolean** within the `if` statement. Any non-zero integer will be equivalent to `True`. This is common in many programming languages.

Answer (score -1):

By design, Python evaluates most values to TRUE. Only a very small set are considered FALSE.

This ends up being a very nice feature when we are doing things like testing for empty values, or iterating over conditional loops.

See section 5.1 in the docs!

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: it has nothing to do with "erroring" on the side of anything - non-zero integers are truthy.

Comment: I removed the idiom "to error on the side of". I can see that it might be confusing. Otherwise, I don't know why you are down voting this answer.